# What is the easiest way to encrypt a password when I save it to the registry?

Tags: c#, encryption, passwords

Currently I'm writing it in clear text *oops!*, it's an in house program so it's not that bad but I'd like to do it right. How should I go about encrypting this when writing to the registry and how do I decrypt it?

```
OurKey.SetValue("Password", textBoxPassword.Text);
```

Comment: There's an answer in a related question - [Simple 2 way encryption for C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165808/simple-2-way-encryption-for-c)

Comment: You could ask the user a password to encrypt the data. Split the string into char array and cast the characters into integer and sum all the integers. Shift each byte in the string by the sum and it'll be secured.

Answer (score 140):

## You don't decrypt authentication passwords!

Hash them using something like the SHA256 provider and when you have to challenge, hash the input from the user and see if the two hashes match.

```
byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputString);
data = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(data);
String hash = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
```

Leaving passwords reversible is a *really* horrible model.

Edit2: I thought we were just talking about front-line authentication. Sure there are cases where you want to encrypt passwords for other things that need to be reversible but there should be a 1-way lock on top of it all (with a very few exceptions).

I've upgraded the hashing algorithm but for the best possible strength you want to keep [a private salt and add that to your input *before* hashing it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2138429/12870). You would do this again when you compare. This adds another layer making it even harder for somebody to reverse.

Comment: What if you're saving it because you need to connect to a network drive when the computer starts, for example?  The question wasn't specific enough to say if using a hash would be possible.

Comment: Generally, it is a bad idea to store passwords, but there are legitimate reasons to do so.  Maybe not in the registry, but...  For example, I have a web application that needs to access a web service using a service id/password.  I store that encrypted in the web config.

Comment: I see, yes, I should have clarified the statement with "authentication". *Edits*

Comment: The point is, *you* don't store passwords anywhere because 11 times out of 10 *you* are guaranteed to do it no better than if you had just stored it in cleartext. If you store keyed or salted hashes, then the original passwords can never be recovered (that's a good thing)!

Comment: Why demand justification for down votes? If you think it should be mandatory vote for the change to UI.

Comment: "Leaving passwords reversible is a really horrible model." - if you want to save passwords needed to authenticate to an external service, there's no alternative.  CredUI is provided for secure storage of encrypted passwords.

Comment: @Mark: so he can address the reasons for the down-votes by improving his answer.

Comment: md5 is a bad way to hash passwords.  Using sha256 with a seed is a much better method.  Or at least encrypt the password with a seed and then perform an md5 hash on it.

Comment: **Please don't recommend MD5.** [MD5 is not safe for securing passwords.](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/) [MD5 will get you and your company in the news for the wrong reasons.](http://www.h-online.com/security/news/item/Password-leaks-bigger-than-first-thought-1614516.html) [MD5 is easy to break.](http://www.golubev.com/hashgpu.htm) I repeat: [MD5 is easy to break.](http://stacksmashing.net/2010/11/15/cracking-in-the-cloud-amazons-new-ec2-gpu-instances/) **Don't recommend SHA-1 either** for the same reasons. ***Do* recommend PBKDF2, bcrypt, or even scrypt.**

Comment: This answer is the top hit for ["c# hash password example"](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=c%23%20hash%20password%20example). Please, think of the children.

Comment: @NickChammas Submit an edit rather than comments. It's just there as a code example.

Comment: I'm not comfortable enough with C# to edit in an alternative in code, but obviously I encourage you to least add a note to your answer calling out the known dangers of using MD5 to hash passwords.

Comment: 1) Don't recommend SHA-2 as password hash, it's almost as bad as MD5 for that purpose. Follow Nick's recommendation instead. 2) You code silently replaces all non ASCII characters by question marks. So a password containing mostly non-ASCII characters will become *much* weaker. Use UTF-8 instead. 3) Don't use ASCII for the output either. Use Base64 or hex instead.

Comment: Please, don't recommend Encoding.ASCII... This kills an ability to use international characters in the password. Consider UTF8 everywhere as universal fallback... with some exceptions where UTF16 might be more appropriate (like performance of in-memory operations).

Answer (score 26):

Please also consider "salting" your hash (not a culinary concept!). Basically, that means appending some random text to the password before you hash it.

"[The salt value helps to slow an attacker perform a dictionary attack should your credential store be compromised, giving you additional time to detect and react to the compromise.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998372.aspx)"

To store password hashes:

a) Generate a random salt value:

```
byte[] salt = new byte[32];
System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider.Create().GetBytes(salt);
```

b) Append the salt to the password.

```
// Convert the plain string pwd into bytes
byte[] plainTextBytes = System.Text UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText);
// Append salt to pwd before hashing
byte[] combinedBytes = new byte[plainTextBytes.Length + salt.Length];
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(plainTextBytes, 0, combinedBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, combinedBytes, plainTextBytes.Length, salt.Length);
```

c) Hash the combined password & salt:

```
// Create hash for the pwd+salt
System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm hashAlgo = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed();
byte[] hash = hashAlgo.ComputeHash(combinedBytes);
```

d) Append the salt to the resultant hash.

```
// Append the salt to the hash
byte[] hashPlusSalt = new byte[hash.Length + salt.Length];
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(hash, 0, hashPlusSalt, 0, hash.Length);
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, hashPlusSalt, hash.Length, salt.Length);
```

e) Store the result in your user store database.

This approach means you don't need to store the salt separately and then recompute the hash using the salt value and the plaintext password value obtained from the user.

**Edit**: As raw computing power becomes cheaper and faster, the value of hashing -- or salting hashes -- has declined. [Jeff Atwood has an excellent 2012 update](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/speed-hashing.html) too lengthy to repeat in its entirety here which states:

> This (using salted hashes) will provide the illusion of security more than any actual security. Since you need both the salt and the choice of hash algorithm to generate the hash, and to check the hash, it's unlikely an attacker would have one but not the other. If you've been compromised to the point that an attacker has your password database, it's reasonable to assume they either have or can get your secret, hidden salt.
>
> The first rule of security is to always assume and plan for the worst.
>   Should you use a salt, ideally a random salt for each user? Sure, it's
>   definitely a good practice, and at the very least it lets you
>   disambiguate two users who have the same password. But these days,
>   salts alone can no longer save you from a person willing to spend a
>   few thousand dollars on video card hardware, and if you think they
>   can, you're in trouble.

Comment: "appending some random text" makes it sound a little dodgy. The text is static for the database, no? The challenge has to go through the same process so.. yeah.. Store the salt or use a salt based on static data (username, user ID, etc).

Comment: I've done both static and random text. I believe the argument for random is that if a really determined hacker manages to figure out the static salt text, then they know the salt for all passwords. OTOH, there is a performance hit involved in generating the random salt text.

Comment: He's been storing this in plaintext and you're worried about salt? Seriously?

Comment: Generating a random salt is overkill.  UserID will make it unique per user.  If you want to change it periodically the last login timestamp will provide a series of continually changing values.

Comment: @Dan Neely: You're going to use UserID for salt? In the big companies I work for, UserID is public information. We're trying to salt with something not easily guessed by a hacker. If salt is a predictable pattern, that just makes it easier to hack. I'm sticking with Microsoft Patterns & Practices Security Practices (the linked article, which, yes, is "retired").

Comment: @DOK If the password database is already compromised, then the salt is known to the attacker - the salt isn't meant to be secret.

Answer (score 16):

Tom Scott got it right in his coverage of how (not) to store passwords, on Computerphile.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q

1. **If you can at all avoid it, do not try to store passwords yourself.** Use a separate, pre-established, trustworthy user authentication platform (e.g.: OAuth providers, you company's Active Directory domain, etc.) instead.
2. **If you must store passwords, don't follow any of the guidance here.** At least, not without also consulting more recent and reputable publications applicable to your language of choice.

There's certainly a lot of smart people here, and probably even some good guidance given. But the odds are strong that, by the time you read this, all of the answers here (including this one) will already be outdated.

---

### The right way to store passwords changes over time.

### ***Probably more frequently than some people change their underwear.***

---

All that said, here's some general guidance that will hopefully remain useful for awhile.

1. ***Don't encrypt passwords.*** Any storage method that allows recovery of the stored data is inherently insecure for the purpose of holding passwords - all forms of encryption included.
2. ***Process the passwords exactly as entered by the user during the creation process.*** Anything you do to the password before sending it to the cryptography module will probably just weaken it. Doing any of the following also just adds complexity to the password storage & verification process, which could cause other problems (perhaps even introduce vulnerabilities) down the road.

   - Don't convert to all-uppercase/all-lowercase.
   - Don't remove whitespace.
   - Don't strip unacceptable characters or strings.
   - Don't change the text encoding.
   - Don't do any character or string substitutions.
   - Don't truncate passwords of any length.
3. ***Reject creation of any passwords that can't be stored without modification.*** Reinforcing the above. If there's some reason your password storage mechanism can't appropriately handle certain characters, whitespaces, strings, or password lengths, then return an error and let the user know about the system's limitations so they can retry with a password that fits within them. For a better user experience, make a list of those limitations accessible to the user up-front. Don't even worry about, let alone bother, hiding the list from attackers - they'll figure it out easily enough on their own anyway.
4. ***Use a long, random, and unique salt for each account.*** No two accounts' passwords should ever look the same in storage, even if the passwords are actually identical.
5. ***Use slow and cryptographically strong hashing algorithms that are designed for use with passwords.*** MD5 is certainly out. SHA-1/SHA-2 are no-go. But I'm not going to tell you what you *should* use here either. (See the first #2 bullet in this post.)
6. ***Iterate as much as you can tolerate.*** While your system might have better things to do with its processor cycles than hash passwords all day, the people who will be cracking your passwords have systems that don't. Make it as hard on them as you can, without quite making it "too hard" on you.

---

Most importantly...

### Don't just listen to anyone here.

Go look up a reputable and very recent publication on the proper methods of password storage for your language of choice. Actually, you should find multiple recent publications from multiple separate sources that are in agreement before you settle on one method.

It's extremely possible that everything that everyone here (myself included) has said has already been superseded by better technologies or rendered insecure by newly developed attack methods. Go find something that's more probably not.

Comment: Nice answer, but "Most importantly...Don't just listen to anyone here. Go look up a reputable ..." -  errr, don't you accept what this site here is made for? How many books shall the TO (possibly) buy and read to have a better answer than in SO - by its mechanisms?

Answer (score 12):

This is what you would like to do:

```
OurKey.SetValue("Password", StringEncryptor.EncryptString(textBoxPassword.Text));
OurKey.GetValue("Password", StringEncryptor.DecryptString(textBoxPassword.Text));
```

You can do that with this the following classes.
This class is a generic class is the client endpoint. It enables IOC of various encryption algorithms using [Ninject](http://ninject.org).

```
public class StringEncryptor
{
    private static IKernel _kernel;

    static StringEncryptor()
    {
        _kernel = new StandardKernel(new EncryptionModule());
    }

    public static string EncryptString(string plainText)
    {
        return _kernel.Get<IStringEncryptor>().EncryptString(plainText);
    }

    public static string DecryptString(string encryptedText)
    {
        return _kernel.Get<IStringEncryptor>().DecryptString(encryptedText);
    }
}
```

This next class is the ninject class that allows you to inject the various algorithms:

```
public class EncryptionModule : StandardModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IStringEncryptor>().To<TripleDESStringEncryptor>();
    }
}
```

This is the interface that any algorithm needs to implement to encrypt/decrypt strings:

```
public interface IStringEncryptor
{
    string EncryptString(string plainText);
    string DecryptString(string encryptedText);
}
```

This is a implementation using the TripleDES algorithm:

```
public class TripleDESStringEncryptor : IStringEncryptor
{
    private byte[] _key;
    private byte[] _iv;
    private TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider _provider;

    public TripleDESStringEncryptor()
    {
        _key = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("GSYAHAGCBDUUADIADKOPAAAW");
        _iv = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("USAZBGAW");
        _provider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    }

    #region IStringEncryptor Members

    public string EncryptString(string plainText)
    {
        return Transform(plainText, _provider.CreateEncryptor(_key, _iv));
    }

    public string DecryptString(string encryptedText)
    {
        return Transform(encryptedText, _provider.CreateDecryptor(_key, _iv));
    }

    #endregion

    private string Transform(string text, ICryptoTransform transform)
    {
        if (text == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(stream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                byte[] input = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text);
                cryptoStream.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

                return Encoding.Default.GetString(stream.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can watch my video and download the code for this at : http://www.wrightin.gs/2008/11/how-to-encryptdecrypt-sensitive-column-contents-in-nhibernateactive-record-video.html

Comment: So, scraping away all the cruft, this response suggests using [TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledes.aspx) (I generally wouldn't use 3DES when [AES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes.aspx) and other "modern" encryption services are available.)

Comment: @pst He's demonstrating how to make your implementation pluggable with any encryption method, rather than recommending any particular method. It's good to be able to swap it out as encryption cracking techniques advance over time.

Answer (score 10):

One option would be to store the hash (SHA1, MD5) of the password instead of the clear-text password, and whenever you want to see if the password is good, just compare it to that hash.

If you need secure storage (for example for a password that you will use to connect to a service), then the problem is more complicated.

If it is just for authentication, then it would be enough to use the hash.

Comment: SHA1/MD5 for passwords? No. Hell no.

Comment: @Iszi - the question and the answer are from 8 years ago

Comment: @Bogdan_Maxim - And my comment you're replying to is from 5 months ago. Your point? Besides, I'm pretty sure that even in '08 SHA1 and MD5 were not acceptable hashing algorithms for secure password storage.

Comment: Definitely now we're in 2020 and I've seen your reply. 4 years later. Anyway, clearly my answer is crap :) it didn't even include the salting which at that time i think it was recommended. Definitely SHA2 was supported at that time but it wasn't that popular. Reading the question I think almost all of the answers went a bit overboard on the password thing. How do we know that the guy actually wanted to save a hash of a password and not implement a "save password" feature? we don't know but look at us talking more than 11 years later about this.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to be able to decrypt the password, I think the easiest way would be to use DPAPI (user store mode) to encrypt/decrypt. This way you don't have to fiddle with encryption keys, store them somewhere or hard-code them in your code - in both cases somebody can discover them by looking into registry, user settings or using Reflector.

Otherwise use hashes SHA1 or MD5 like others have said here.

Comment: SHA1 & MD5 are *not* appropriate for password hashing.

Answer (score 6):

Like ligget78 said, DPAPI would be a good way to go for storing passwords. [Check out the ProtectedData class on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx) for example usage.

Answer (score 6):

I have looked all over for a good example of encryption and decryption process but most were overly complex.

Anyhow there are many reasons someone may want to decrypt some text values including passwords. The reason I need to decrypt the password on the site I am working on currently is because they want to make sure when someone is forced to change their password when it expires that we do not let them change it with a close variant of the same password they used in the last x months.

So I wrote up a process that will do this in a simplified manner. I hope this code is beneficial to someone. For all I know I may end up using this at another time for a different company/site.

```
public string GenerateAPassKey(string passphrase)
    {
        // Pass Phrase can be any string
        string passPhrase = passphrase;
        // Salt Value can be any string(for simplicity use the same value as used for the pass phrase)
        string saltValue = passphrase;
        // Hash Algorithm can be "SHA1 or MD5"
        string hashAlgorithm = "SHA1";
        // Password Iterations can be any number
        int passwordIterations = 2;
        // Key Size can be 128,192 or 256
        int keySize = 256;
        // Convert Salt passphrase string to a Byte Array
        byte[] saltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue);
        // Using System.Security.Cryptography.PasswordDeriveBytes to create the Key
        PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltValueBytes, hashAlgorithm, passwordIterations);
        //When creating a Key Byte array from the base64 string the Key must have 32 dimensions.
        byte[] Key = pdb.GetBytes(keySize / 11);
        String KeyString = Convert.ToBase64String(Key);

        return KeyString;
    }

 //Save the keystring some place like your database and use it to decrypt and encrypt
//any text string or text file etc. Make sure you dont lose it though.

 private static string Encrypt(string plainStr, string KeyString)        
    {            
        RijndaelManaged aesEncryption = new RijndaelManaged();
        aesEncryption.KeySize = 256;
        aesEncryption.BlockSize = 128;
        aesEncryption.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        aesEncryption.Padding = PaddingMode.ISO10126;
        byte[] KeyInBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(KeyString);
        aesEncryption.Key = KeyInBytes;
        byte[] plainText = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainStr);
        ICryptoTransform crypto = aesEncryption.CreateEncryptor();
        byte[] cipherText = crypto.TransformFinalBlock(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherText);
    }

 private static string Decrypt(string encryptedText, string KeyString) 
    {
        RijndaelManaged aesEncryption = new RijndaelManaged(); 
        aesEncryption.KeySize = 256;
        aesEncryption.BlockSize = 128; 
        aesEncryption.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        aesEncryption.Padding = PaddingMode.ISO10126;
        byte[] KeyInBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(KeyString);
        aesEncryption.Key = KeyInBytes;
        ICryptoTransform decrypto = aesEncryption.CreateDecryptor(); 
        byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64CharArray(encryptedText.ToCharArray(), 0, encryptedText.Length); 
        return ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypto.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length)); 
    }

 String KeyString = GenerateAPassKey("PassKey");
 String EncryptedPassword = Encrypt("25Characterlengthpassword!", KeyString);
 String DecryptedPassword = Decrypt(EncryptedPassword, KeyString);
```

Answer (score 5):

If it's a password used for authentication by your application, then hash the password as others suggest.

If you're storing passwords for an external resource, you'll often want to be able to prompt the user for these credentials and give him the opportunity to save them securely.  Windows provides the Credentials UI (CredUI) for this purpose - there are a number of samples showing how to use this in .NET, including [this one on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302353.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

..NET provides cryptographics services in class contained in the
System.Security.Cryptography namespace.

Comment: This answer is so broad it's useless. Choosing the right crypto and implementing it correctly is the difficult part, and not finding where the crypto classes are.

Answer (score 1):

If you need more than this, for example securing a connection string (for connection to a database), check this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b(VS.80).aspx), as it provides the best "option" for this.

Oli's answer is also good, as it shows how you can create a hash for a string.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than encrypt/decrypt, you should be passing the password through a hashing algorithm, md5/sha512, or similar. What you would ideally do is hash the password and store the hash, then when the password is needed, you hash the entry and compare the entries.  A password will then never be "decrypted", simply hashed and then compared.

Comment: MD5 for passwords? NO.

Comment: @TomDoodler In short, two reasons: 1. It's broken. 2. It's *fast*.

Comment: So what would you recommend for storing passwords?