# How can you set a password that can't be found in the source code?

Tags: c#, passwords, hidden

Basically, I have an application that will be used by different people. When a specific person logs on, they are asked to give a password to receive extra permissions. How can I set this password, preferably online, for ease of changing it, but not have it visible in the source code?

Comment: You have put the cart way in front of the horse here. Start with a thorough *threat model analysis* before you try to implement your own security system. You need to be able to answer questions like: what resource are you protecting? From what threat? How is it vulnerable to the threat? What are the consequences of a successful attack? And so on.  Only after that analysis is complete should you even begin to contemplate solutions like password protection. Password protection schemes are *extraordinarily difficult to get right*.  Hire a professional who specializes in this.

Comment: Either I messed up my explanation, or you interpreted it very incorrectly...

Comment: I would strongly consider generating a `HashSet` and storing that.  There are a few examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236667/c-sharp-storing-user-password-for-comparison) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181198/how-to-hash-a-password).

Answer (score 2):

Put a hashed version of the password in a database.  When someone logs in, calculate the hash of the password they entered, and compare this with the password in the DB.

Answer (score -1):

If not online, you could save the password in the registry or in a configuration file opportunely encrypted and compare.

If online, you can use a web service that compare the password and returns a boolean.