# AES 256 java and .Net compatible encryption and decryption?

Tags: java, c#, aes

I want to do the AES 256 encryption/decryption using Java and .Net. Which Means i should be able to encrypt with Java and decrypt with .Net and Vice vesra. Following is the Java AES 256 encryption.

```
byte[] iv = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(KEY.toCharArray(), SALT.getBytes(), 65536, 256);
SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
System.out.println(Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES"));
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
```

Answer (score 4):

1) The Java-decryption part is given by

```
byte[] iv = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(KEY.toCharArray(), SALT.getBytes(), 65536, 256);
SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(strToDecrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
```

where `strToDecrypt` are the Base64 encoded encrypted data (given by the return value of the encryption part) and which deviates from the encryption part only in the last two lines.

*Note:* In practice, the IV should be randomly generated (e.g. [Generating random IV for AES in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267435/generating-random-iv-for-aes-in-java)). But I assume that's clear and the 0-sequence is just for testing purposes.

2) Concerning the key derivation `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256` the C#-solution depends on your .NET-framework version. For V4.7.2 and above the key can be derived with:

```
// .NET Framework 4.7.2 +
byte[] secretKey = null;
using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(KEY, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SALT), 65536, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256))   
{
    secretKey = rfc2898.GetBytes(32);                                                                                                                                                                                
}
```

*Note:* Previous implementations (prior to v4.7.2) of `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` use `SHA1` (hard coded) instead of `SHA256` and thus, there's no ctor expecting 4 parameters. Moreover, the `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`-class requires a salt-length of at least 8 bytes, otherwise a `System.ArgumentException: Salt is not at least eight bytes` is thrown.

An alternative is:

```
// .NET Framework 4.5 + 
byte[] secretKey = null;
KeyDerivationPrf keyDerivationPrf = KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA256;
secretKey = KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(KEY, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SALT), keyDerivationPrf, 65536, 32);
```

The latter works for V4.6.1 and above, but you need the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation.KeyDerivation`-class which 
you can find e.g. at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation/. For the installation you can 
use e.g. the Package Manager Console (Tools - NuGet Package Manager - Package Manager Console). Just enter the corresponding command as described in the link.
Maybe you get an IDE-error `CS0012`. In this case you have to add `<Reference Include="netstandard" />` to the reference-section of your `csproj`-file (see also https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/542). The `KeyDerivationPrf`-class doesn't restrict the salt-length.

There are also other possibilities (like Bouncy Castle) which I didn't try, but maybe they are better alternatives for you. This topic is also discussed at [Rfc2898 / PBKDF2 with SHA256 as digest in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648084/rfc2898-pbkdf2-with-sha256-as-digest-in-c-sharp).

3) An example for the C#-encryption-method is:

```
public string Encrypt(string plainText)
{
    // PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256 Key derivation
    // ...

    using (RijndaelManaged cipher = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        cipher.Key = secretKey;
        cipher.IV = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        cipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        cipher.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        byte[] encryptedData;
        using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = cipher.CreateEncryptor())
        {
            using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
                    {
                        streamWriter.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    encryptedData = memoryStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }

        return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
    }
}
```

where `plainText` is a string containing your plain text (corresponding to `strToEncrypt`). The encrypted data become base64 encoded and are returned as string (analogous to your Java-method).

Test case:

```
String KEY = "The Password";
String SALT = "The Salt";
byte[] iv = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

gives

```
Plain text:       This is a plain text that needs to be encrypted
Key (hex):        2D7664713D701C58FC506F93CEA3194671AD3B5C034255A4AC04AF46EADC89BC
Base64 encoded
encrypted data:   ksUYjmbP9ga39LXr3wXQ34Bp32UlloYPxg3WWuW0iovWbg/GxHJrIuF3jrDvjr/Q
```

4) An example for the C#-decryption-method is:

```
public string Decrypt(string encryptedText)
{
    // PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256 Key derivation
    // ...

    using (RijndaelManaged cipher = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        cipher.Key = secretKey;
        cipher.IV = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        cipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        cipher.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        string decryptedText;
        using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = cipher.CreateDecryptor())
        {
            using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText)))
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
                    {
                        decryptedText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return decryptedText;
    }
}
```

where `encryptedText` is the return value of the encryption-part (encrypted data which are base64 encoded, corresponding to `strToDecrypt`). The method returns the decrypted text (analogous to the Java-method).