# C# Key Generation for password management

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I am using the Aesmanaged class to encrypt/decrypt passwords, per the code in this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged(v=vs.110).aspx

We have a system to store user passwords encrypted. My question is do we store the user passwords with one key/IV pair for all users or one Key/IV pair for each user. What are the pros/cons for each approach?

Comment: You really shouldn't encrypt your users' passwords. You should hash them with a per user salt and many iterations (PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt).

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I did browse through in the direction you mentioned and yes, it makes a lot of sense. In doing so I came across this question: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80623/hashing-vs-one-way-encryption, which I guess is the way to go. Or is there a better practice?

Comment: Since there is no code, it is not really helpful. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10402129/1816580) much more helpful, but nowadays you should specify a couple million iterations.

Comment: Thank you. I am unable to mark this as the answer to my question, let me know how i can do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hash a password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181198/how-to-hash-a-password)

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment. That is why you can't accept it. Technically, I didn't answer your question. However, you should see a button above your question mark it as a duplicate of another question which should answer your actual problem. Be aware of the [X Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/266187) in the future.