# Using a hash to protect password in file

Tags: c#, forms, hash

I've had a look around around SO and found some useful info on using a hash, but not actually any information on how to use it with the `StreamWriter` function in C#.

The code I used from SO was the code I found here: [How to hash a password - Christian Gollhardt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181198/how-to-hash-a-password/10402129#10402129)

**CODE**

```
 private void Accept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        usrpass = usrpassTextbox.Text.ToString();
        usrid = usridTextbox.Text.ToString();

            if (FileExists() == true)
                {
                if (DialogResult.OK == MessageBox.Show("This user already exists, overwrite?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel))
                    {
                    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(usrid + ".txt"))
                    { 
                        streamWriter.WriteLine(usrpass);
                        MessageBox.Show(id + "'s password has been saved");
                    }
                    }
                }
            else
            {
                using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(usrid + ".txt"))
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(usrpass);
                MessageBox.Show(id + " " + "'s password has been saved");
            }
        }
    }
```

Also I am considering putting the saving into a method to reduce code, I know there's no point in  writing it out twice.

**Desired Outcome**

I would like the password that is being written to the `.txt` file to be hashed, if this is hashed, will the user still be able to login when I write a bit of code that checks if the user's txt file exists, then reads it for the password?

Will I have to unhash it?

As of yet, I have the code I borrowed from Christian but not sure how to use it to hash the `usrpass`before it is written to file

Comment: You can't *unhash* since hashing is *one way* only. You have to compare hashes (password's hash and user input's one)

Comment: I see, is this common-folk friendly? As in  - would a user have to save a given hash in order to successfully log in?

Comment: I found this thread interesting on hashing: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11717/why-are-hash-functions-one-way-if-i-know-the-algorithm-why-cant-i-calculate-t

Comment: You cant unhash it - thats the point of hashing.  Convert the PBKDF2 result (better than MD5) to a base64 string if you are saving to a text file.  Then to log in or whatever you are doing, ask for the PW, hash it and see if the hashes match (after converting the B64 back to bytes).  I have no idea how you plan to track multiple users/pws in one file

Comment: Plutonix - each user has a seperate file according to their ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static string CreateMD5(string input)
    {
        // Use input string to calculate MD5 hash
        using (System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
        {
            byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
            byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

            // Convert the byte array to hexadecimal string
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(hashBytes[i].ToString("X2"));
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

...

```
 usrpass = CreateMD5(usrpassTextbox.Text.ToString());
```

Comment: Is this answer dependent on Christians information on hashing or is this independent?

Comment: It's totally different solution with same result.

Comment: Will this make `logging in` impossible? As in, reading the users password file to check if the password is correct? How can this be achieved when it is hashed

Comment: Keep hashed passwords in database. That's the way it should be done. You can check if `hash(password)` = `hash_from_database`, but you can't (well it would be really hard) decode `hash_from_database` to `password`.

Comment: I see, that is a shame