# List of invalid symbols for password or any string inputs (for c# and mssql)

Tags: c#, sql-server

Client wants us to allow all possible symbols for password inputs but what I know is that there are some characters that can ruin a code like

"double quotation (")" for c# coding

```
string name = "jose" jose"
```

"single quotation (')" for mssql

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) = 'jose' jose'
```

"ampersand (&)" and "vertical line for or (|)" possible for sql injection in mssql

and "backslash (\)" like this sample that it is used for character escape. (it is actually double slash to show)

Is there any symbols am I missing or I made a wrong idea with the symbols declared?

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to pass parameters to your sql query. Instead use real sql-parameters. Otherwise you are open for sql injection and other issues(conversion, broken sql, localization,...).

Comment: None of these symbols ruin code if handled correctly. You shouldn't be worrying about symbols in passwords anyway as you shouldn't be storing passwords as strings. This smells like something else is wrong.

Comment: @Equalsk if I will convert string to encrypted or hashed values, then I won't have a problem? like if my input to my text box in c# is jose"jose, c# can still understand that and will encrypt it? I'm just worried about having a "jose"jose" value that will break the string to "jose" and will have a problem on next jose"

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks for the reminder. I'll take note of that.

Comment: Yes, you can encrypt a string containing any of the characters you've mentioned. A basic example is that when the user enters their password you compare the hash of the entered password to the stored hash to see if they match.

Comment: I tried it and yes it's working without a problem, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No symbol is harmful when you store passwords correctly.
There are only 2 rules for that:

1. **Always** use parameters when passing data to the database.
   This is the only effective way to prevent SQL Injection attacks.
2. **Never** store plain text passwords in your database.
   Instead, store a salted hash value representing the password.

You can read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181198/how-to-hash-a-password/10402129#10402129) on how to hash passwords,
and [some more information on Microsoft Docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/password-hashing)

Edit:
Just found quite a long [article on CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/704865/Salted-Password-Hashing-Doing-it-Right) that explains in details why and how to hash passwords.

Answer (score 0):

for C# code you will need to add \ before each double quotation

```
string name = "jose\" jose"
```

for SQL server you will need to add an extra quote:

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) = 'jose'' jose'
```