# Passing Values while avoiding System.NullReferenceException ERROR

Tags: c#, sql, database, authentication, error-handling

How to pass value entered by User while login to another form without having System.NullReferenceException ERROR ??

I'm Using a Class to help in passing the value from one form to another, the class code is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StudentFollowUp
{
    public class Student
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and then i made a login page where the user can enter his username and password and i made the connection with the database and when i run the code below i get this sentence :"An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in StudentFollowUp.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Here is the code and thank in advance :

```
private void loginlable_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\StudentFollowup.mdf;Integrated Security=True;"))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) From Users Where Username = '" + username.Text + "' and Password = '" + password.Text + "'", Connection);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                StudentInfo.username = username.Text;
                StudentInfo.password = password.Text;

                sda.Fill(dt);

                if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    Main ss = new Main();
                    ss.Show();
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Check Your Username and Password");
                }       

            }
}
```

Comment: And just a hint, always when you have a null reference exception, check what exactly is the null object in the debugger, my guess is that your DataTable is null when you try to call ToString() inside the if.

Comment: `\''; DROP TABLE users; --`

Comment: Debug your code and you will find what object Is null. It could be StudentInfo. It could be dt.Rows[0][0]

Comment: Never concatenate user input into sql statements. [Always use parameters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892166/how-does-sqlparameter-prevent-sql-injection) Also, [never store passwords as plain text in your database.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47691482/3094533)

Comment: read bobby-tables.com .. and then throw all this code away and read a good tutorial on Entity Framework, and never write an SQL statement into a string in your code again (please)

Comment: The compiler show me that the null objects are at the code lines :  StudentInfo.username = username.Text;
StudentInfo.password = password.Text;