# Encrypt/Hash password table in SQL SERVER Compact 4.0

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, sdf

is there a way to encrypt/hash the table password in SQL CE 4.0? I have a table here in USERACCOUNT table Password. I want to encrypt/hash the text then insert it to my table Password. Then I want to select the Password which is encrypted/hash[TABLEUSERACCOUNT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61UMR.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hash a password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181198/how-to-hash-a-password)

Comment: already done it by using FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(TxtPassword.Text, "MD5"); tnx btw :)