# SQL Server : delete user

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to write a query to delete a user registration from my SQL Server database, but when I try to delete a user, I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.'

My code:

```
Public Class DeleteForm
Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    Dim conn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=dbProject;Integrated Security=True")

    Using cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblLogin WHERE username = " & txtUsername.Text, conn)
        conn.Open()
        Dim reader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If reader.Read = True Then
            If txtUserPass.Text = txtCheckPass.Text Then
                Dim deleteOk As Integer = MessageBox.Show("This cant be undone!" & vbCrLf & "Are you sure?", "Warning!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
                If deleteOk = DialogResult.Yes Then
                    Dim queryDelete As String = "DELETE FROM tblLogin WHERE username = " & txtUsername.Text & " and password = " & txtPassword.Text
                    Dim cmdDelete As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(queryDelete, conn)

                    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Open()
                    reader.Close()
                    cmdDelete.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MsgBox("Cancellazione eseguita correttamente!")
                    cmdDelete.Dispose()
                    conn.Close()
                ElseIf deleteOk = DialogResult.No Then

                End If
            Else
                MsgBox("The passwords arent matching!")
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("User not found")
            conn.Close()
            txtUsername.Clear()
            txtUsername.Focus()
            txtUserPass.Clear()
            txtCheckPass.Clear()
        End If
    End Using
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Which line is it erroring on?

Comment: Just a suggestion. I would separate this in multiple method. One that look if the user exists, an other that just delete and one that calls them and handle error.

Comment: Be aware of SQL injection! Always use parametrized queries.

Comment: Not using parameters is just awful. This is wide open to sql injection and my friend [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) loves this style of coding. And passwords should be salted and hashed, not stored in clear text.

Comment: Never ever store passwords as plain text either - salt them and hash them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>You need to open connection before you can create a command. 
i.e.</strike>

```
Dim conn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=dbProject;Integrated Security=True")
conn.Open()
Using cmd = New SqlCommand(....
```

However your current code contains [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). You should not concatenate strings go get your SQL. You should use parameters. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7505842/809357) for better explanation about the application.

Also it is never a good practice to store passwords in plain text. Ever. You should store hash of password only and compare the hashes rather than plain-text. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10402129/809357) for reference. And [more background info](https://medium.com/@mehanix/lets-talk-security-salted-password-hashing-in-c-5460be5c3aae) on why you should hash

Comment: "You need to open connection before you can create a command." I know you have way more experience than I but, I do not agree. An instantiated connection can be sent to the Command constructor. It does not need to be open. I never open a connection until the last possible moment; right before the Execute.

Comment: @Mary Huh, you are absolutely correct here - I did not realise that, I always opened connection before passing it to commands (though this is a very rare occasion I writ this low-level code)