# Login Comparing hash value in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcommand, scalar, executenonquery

I am attempting to make a simple sign on portion of an app I am creating. To confirm sign in, I am just attempting to make sure that the hash value of the password entered, matches that which is stored in my local database: **App_Users**  ) '

ButtonClick:

```
        string AppUsername = textBox2.Text.ToString();
        string AppPassword = textBox1.Text.ToString();
        //- Hashed-V-
        byte[] salt;
        new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(salt = new byte[16]);
        var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(AppPassword, salt, 10000);
        byte[] hash = pbkdf2.GetBytes(20);
        byte[] hashBytes = new byte[36];
        Array.Copy(salt, 0, hashBytes, 0, 16);
        Array.Copy(hash, 0, hashBytes, 16, 20);
        string savedPasswordHash = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);                                                                   //              <--  see ' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181198/how-to-hash-a-password ' for the part on comparing the recalculated 
        //-
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=DESKTOP-PGHMM6M;Initial Catalog=LocalUsers;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();                

        var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT Username, Hash FROM App_Users WHERE (Hash = @Hash");
        cmd.Connection = con;
        savedPasswordHash = cmd.ExecuteScalar() as string;

        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0) {
            MessageBox.Show(" Query successful..something matched..  ");
            //change page.. load a profile? 
        }
```

However, I am getting the error:

```
 'Must declare the scalar variable "@Hash".'
```

I've searched around but I'm not sure what the next step for exactly what I am trying to do is.. Sorry this is probably a bad question, sql-wise. I think it has something to do with an adapter?

Comment: if you use parameters, you actually have to add them! See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/commands-and-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't pass a value for the `@Hash` parameter in the query. And you should also check for the user name in the query or else the login attempt is successful if **any** login uses the given password.

Try something like:

```
...
var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT Username, Hash FROM App_Users WHERE Hash = @Hash AND Username = @Username");
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Hash", SqlDbType.VarChar, 48).Value = savedPasswordHash;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 32).Value = AppUsername;

if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0) {
...
```

This assumes, that `App_Users.Hash` is a `VARCHAR(48)` and `App_Users` an `NVARCHAR(32)`. You may need to change it to match the data types you're actually using.

Comment: Definitely my mistake >.< Thank you! it's no longer throwing any errors. It's still not showing the messageBox though. Is there any other trick to confirm it's working? ( besides executenonquery)