# How to Encrypt Password with public key in angular and Decrypt the password with private key in C#

Tags: c#, .net, angular, angular7, encryption-asymmetric

I am stuck into a task where I want to Encrypt the user password with RSA public key into Angular 7 and same decrypt with private key into C#
Please help me into this task
Many many thanks in advance.

Comment: Never encrypt a password, you should hash it.

Comment: How can I do that do you have some reference

Comment: Go through this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181198/how-to-hash-a-password/10402129#10402129

Comment: Also, consider using SSL certificates

Comment: You should never store a password in plain text, therefore you should not be encrypting/decrypting a password to be able to do that comparison.  As @PSK says, you hash a password and compare that hash against the hash you stored originally.

Comment: But I want to do this between two platforms Angular and .Net How can I do that in Angular

Comment: Hash the password and send it to .NET. Never encrypt a password. You hash it so you can't know what it is, when the user logs in, you has the password they give and see if it matches the one you have stored.

Comment: Do you have some angular reference where we can hash the password

Comment: @VIVEK https://auth0.com/blog/hashing-passwords-one-way-road-to-security/

Comment: have a read of this, quite interesting and may help in the road to hashing the password https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110948/password-hashing-on-frontend-or-backend

Comment: Why? I'm not sure what you want to achieve. If you want to make sure that no one who sees the http traffic is able to see the password, encryption doesn't help you at all. Because if I see the http traffic, I can just take the encrypted password and send it to your C# server (without knowing the password!). Your C# will decrypt, see the password is right  and grant me access! The same is true for hashing, I can just send the hashed password and it will match. You can only prevent this by using HTTPS / SSL to encrypt all of the traffic in order to keep me from reading the http traffic.

Comment: "Never encrypt a password, you should hash it." In 99% of the cases: I agree. If you need to store a password for sending e-mails in the name of a customer when the customer is offline, that could be an exception. You need the password to authenticate and there is no user to type it in for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some Link which are help full in this task:

Below libs are helpful in generating RSA Asymmetric Encryption:(Angular)

```
node-rsa: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rsa
quick-encrypt: https://www.npmjs.com/package/quick-encrypt
asymmetric-crypto: https://www.npmjs.com/package/asymmetric-crypto
```

Comment: node-rsa is not supported in Angular 11.

Answer (score 0):

**node-forge can be used at angular**

```
 import * as Forge from 'node-forge';

 encryptWithPublicKey(valueToEncrypt: string): string {
  
    const rsa = Forge.pki.publicKeyFromPem(this.publicKey);
    const encryptedBytes = rsa.encrypt(valueToEncrypt.toString(),'RSAES-PKCS1-V1_5');
    return window.btoa(encryptedBytes)
  }
}
```