# How to insert in some special columns in a table in SQL Server from ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have some columns in table `Tbl_User`, but I want to insert data into two of them - not all - and I don't know how can write this code.

I created a repository and this code save all of data to table:

```
public bool InsertUser(Tbl_User t)
{
    db.Tbl_User.Add(t);
    return Convert.ToBoolean(db.SaveChanges());
}
```

but I want to save just in `UserName` and `Password` columns.

I created a viewmodel like this, but I don't know what shall I do?

```
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   public string Password { get; set; }
```

Comment: *"but i want to save ... Password"*. **don't**. Never store plain text passwords in a database; they should always be salted and hashed.

Comment: [How to hash a password?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10402129/6311045) and [Passwrd hashing in C#](https://janaks.com.np/password-hashing-in-csharp/)

Comment: just search on c# password hash

Answer (score 0):

You can tag the property you do not want stored with [NotMapped]

```
   [NotMapped]
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   public string Password { get; set; }
```

Docs:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute?view=netframework-4.8

Also as Larnu pointed out saving a the password like this is **NOT** advisable.

Comment: How do I save a password?

Comment: You shouldn't be, @sepide725 , as I said.

Comment: If you are dealing with username and passwords you might want to look at Asp.Net Identity.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio