# How to decrypt the encoded string using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

```
 public static byte[] ComputeHashCode(byte[] toBeHashed)
   {
       using (var md5 = SHA512.Create())
       {
           return md5.ComputeHash(toBeHashed);
       }
   }

public static string encodestring(string mystring)
    {
        byte[] encode = new byte[mystring.Length];
        encode = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mystring);
        string s1 = Convert.ToBase64String(ComputeHashCode(encode));
        string strmsg = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s1));
        return strmsg;
    }
```

i am encoded the string using above techniqe but how to decrypt the encoded string. i tried like this below function but not giving expected result.

```
public static string decodestring()
    {
        string strmsg = "dbvsdvjvjhjdfsjdcs==";
        byte[] encode = Convert.FromBase64String(strmsg);

        strmsg = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ComputeHashCode(encode))));
        return strmsg;
    }
```

Comment: Define "not working"

Comment: Define "expected result"... FWIW You can't get `toBeHashed` back, and that's correct for storing a password.

Comment: `SHA512` is a hash function (See - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).  When a value is hashed with such a function, the original string cannot be retrieved.  If you are using this process to verify passwords, then you should hash the user input and compare the resultant value against the original hash - (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10402129/1603275).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hash a password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181198/how-to-hash-a-password)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `SHA512`, a hashing algorithm. Hashing algorithms are meant to be irreversible and cannot be decrypted. This is mostly used for password checks and file integrity checks.

Answer (score 2):

Are you attempting to store data in an encrypted form and then decode it for display at a later date?
If so the a basic hash isn't suitable, instead you'll need an encryption algorithm that uses a known encryption key to encrypt or decrypt it.

If you're handling a password, its best to compare hashed values in order to determine whether a supplied value is correct or not this is to prevent handling of the password in clear text as much as possible.
Here's a utility class do demonstrate that

```
   /// <summary>
/// This is a utility class that can be used to securely hash and verify a password.
/// The output from the Hashing process includes a header to identify that the value
/// has been produced using this code, the salt value used to produce the has and the hash value
/// itself.
/// Note: the salt value is randomly produced for each hashed password.
/// </summary>
public static class PasswordHashUtility
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Size of salt for Hash production
    /// </summary>
    private const int SaltSize = 16;

    /// <summary>
    /// Size of Has
    /// </summary>
    private const int HashSize = 20;

    private const string HashType = "$MBnYt1!?$V1";

    public static int HashIterations = 1000;
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a hash from a password.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="password">The password.</param>
    /// <param name="iterations">Number of iterations.</param>
    /// <returns>The hash</returns>
    public static string Hash(string password, int iterations)
    {
        // Create salt
        var salt = new byte[SaltSize];
        var cryptoServiceProvider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        cryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes(salt);

        // Create hash
        var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, iterations);
        var hash = pbkdf2.GetBytes(HashSize);

        // Combine salt and hash
        var hashBytes = new byte[SaltSize + HashSize];
        Array.Copy(salt, 0, hashBytes, 0, SaltSize);
        Array.Copy(hash, 0, hashBytes, SaltSize, HashSize);

        // Convert to base64
        var base64Hash = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);

        // tidy-up 
        cryptoServiceProvider.Dispose();
        pbkdf2.Dispose();

        // Format hash with extra information
        return $"{HashType}{iterations}${base64Hash}";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if hash has been produced by this utility.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hashString">The hash type name</param>
    /// <returns>True if supported</returns>
    public static bool IsHashSupported(string hashString)
    {
        return hashString.StartsWith(HashType);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Verifies a password against a hash.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="password">The password to verify</param>
    /// <param name="hashedPassword">The hash value to verify against</param>
    /// <returns>Could be verified?</returns>
    public static bool Verify(string password, string hashedPassword)
    {
        // Check hash
        if (!IsHashSupported(hashedPassword))
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("The hash type is not supported");
        }

        // Extract iteration and Base64 string
        var splitHashString = hashedPassword.Replace(HashType, "").Split('$');
        var iterations = int.Parse(splitHashString[0]);
        var base64Hash = splitHashString[1];

        // Get hash bytes
        var hashBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Hash);

        // Get salt
        var salt = new byte[SaltSize];
        Array.Copy(hashBytes, 0, salt, 0, SaltSize);

        // Create hash with given salt
        var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, iterations);
        var hash = pbkdf2.GetBytes(HashSize);

        //tidy-up
        pbkdf2.Dispose();

        // Get result
        for (var i = 0; i < HashSize; i++)
        {
            if (hashBytes[i + SaltSize] != hash[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea of hashing a string, is that it can not be reversed. [This Question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/45377/why-cant-we-reverse-hashes) explains why it is so hard to reverse it. So basically what you are trying to do is not possible as far as I have understood your question.