# How to properly decrypt passwords stored in SQL Server database in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption

I'm a fairly new developer so bear with me, this has given me a headache.

I have been trying to store the passwords for a Winforms application I'm developing in an encrypted format in the database. There is a login and registration interface when the application is first opened.

I have managed to encrypt the password that is given during registration, and it is not in plaintext in the database, and I used a class `Cryptography` for this. However, when I try to decrypt the password to grant the user access to the application I get the exception unhandled error:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

Is there a way to solve this? I cannot figure it out.

The code that does the encryption:

```
public static string Encrypt(string encryptString)
{
        string EncryptionKey = "djknh46hdkkjsdvvjjsijeykskerfubb1906234575";      
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(encryptString);

        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] {
            0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76});
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), 
                CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }

                encryptString = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }

        return encryptString;
}
```

The code that is supposed to do the decryption:

```
public static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
{
        string EncryptionKey = "djknh46hdkkjsdvvjjsijeykskerfubb1906234575";      
        cipherText = cipherText.Replace(" ", "+");
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] {
            0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76});
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), 
                CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }

                cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }

        return cipherText;
}
```

The code that does is supposed to verify the password from the database:

```
string Password = "";
bool IsExist = false;           

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from LibraryUser where UserName='" + 
        txtUsernameLogin.Text + "'", connection1);

SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

if (dataReader.Read())
{
    Password = dataReader.GetString(4);   
    IsExist = true;
}

connection1.Close();

if (IsExist)   
{
    if (Cryptography.Decrypt(Password).Equals(txtPasswordLogin.Text))
    {
        this.Hide();
        new LibraryForm().Show();                 
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The password you have entered is incorrect, please try again.", 
                        "Incorrect Password", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
else  
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter the valid credentials.", "Error", 
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

I appreciate any help anyone has to offer, thanks in advance.

Comment: you shouldn't need to decrypt passwords, because they should only be stored as salted hashes.

Comment: This is not best practice. Always use one way encryption as described above then encrypt the user input in the same way for a match.

Comment: Forgive me, what do you mean? Does this mean I should delete the code that decrypts? What are salted hashes? How do I use them?

Comment: Yes, never decrypt. Google will help with your second question. There must be many good examples around of password management.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter, I will look into salted hashes and replace the code!

Comment: Will look into parametrized queries! Thanks! I have lots of queries in the application so I will definitely be looking into fixing them.

Comment: Here's the latest on hashed passwords.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181198/how-to-hash-a-password/10402129#10402129  **Pro tip** [Read this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php). Even though it's written for php, it contains a good explanation of password security.

Comment: Hopefully you haven't posted your actual encryption keys here. Even if you're _sure_ they're not real, you should be putting nonsense in place of any secrets posted online. :)

Answer (score 1):

The above comments on best practice (one-way encryption, salted hashes, SQL injection) are valid and I fully endorse them.

However, the actual question is: why is the Base64-decoding failing?

The answer is that the value you are reading from the database is not a valid Base64-encoding. This line is suspicious:

```
cipherText = cipherText.Replace(" ", "+");
```

A space is not a valid character in Base64-encoding. What data type are you using to store the string? Is it being returned as a fixed-length string with space padding? If so, you may need to call `.Trim()` on `cipherText` instead of the above line.

If this doesn't work, please post an example of `cipherText` from your `Decrypt()` method which is causing this exception so that we can try to answer your question.

Again, this is not best practice. Please note the comments above by Mitch Wheat, Peter and marc_s.

Answer (score 0):

For passwords, you don't decrypt them, you compare only the encrypted ones.

New user:

```
var hash = Encrypt(password);
DbInsert(userId, hash);
```

Authenticating a user:

```
var hash = Encrypt(password);
var dbHash = GetPasswordFromDb(userId);
if (dbHash == hash) {
    // authenticated
} else {
    // wrong password
}
```

You compare the hashed values because passwords should be impossible to decrypt, such that the only way to discover a password is guessing.

Usually I use [BCrypt.Net-Next NuGet](https://github.com/BcryptNet/bcrypt.net). Its simple to use and secure enough.