# Secure memory to prevent viewing

Tags: c#, winforms, security

I programmed a program in Windows form in C # language and to secure it and not to see the program variables, I have used the following three solutions, but some variables are still observed in memory using the **WinHex** program.

1.obfuscating with **ConfuserEx**

2.using **SecureString**

3.Put the strings in the section  of **App.config**

The related codes are as follows:

Main Code:

```
SecureString ss1 = ConvertToSecureString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SKB"]);
byte[] SKB = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(new NetworkCredential("", ss1).Password);
ss1.Dispose();
```

**SKB**'s value in **App.Config**:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="SKB" value="0164Kfm*" />
</appSettings>
```

**ConvertToSecureString()** Function:

```
public SecureString ConvertToSecureString(string password)
{
   if (password == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("psw");

   var securePassword = new SecureString();
   Array.ForEach(password.ToCharArray(), securePassword.AppendChar);

   securePassword.MakeReadOnly();
   return securePassword;
}
```

The value of SKB is visible in memory by using WinHex:

[WinHex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKWko.jpg)

How can I delete variables value in memory?

Comment: you can't. However you can easily encrypt your data to prevent it from being read. That assumes you decrypt it when checking the password of course.

Comment: the gist of it: if your program is to use the data (whatever data), it needs to have it unencrypted at _some_ point. at that point, an attacker can read it. there's nothing anyone can do about this.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to protect against? Passwords should *never* be stored in clear text, they should *always* be hashed. See [how to hash passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181198/how-to-hash-a-password) for more information. You *cannot* protect against an attacker that has control of the execution environment. At best you can delegate sensitive operations to a special secure hardware chip.

Comment: If the user has admin access then there is **nothing** you can do to fully prevent them