# Is SHA1 still secure for use as hash function in PBKDF2?

Tags: cryptography, hash, sha1, pbkdf2

As there have been significant advances in the cryptoanalysis of SHA1 it's supposed to be phased out in favor of SHA2 ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1)).

For use as underlying hash function in PBKDF2, however, it's basically used as a PRNG. As such it should be still secure to use SHA1 as hash for PBKDF2, right?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

None of the currently known weaknesses on SHA-1 has any impact on its security when used in HMAC, *a fortiori* when used in PBKDF2. For that matter, MD5 would be fine too (but not MD4).

However, SHA-1 is not good for public relations: if, in 2011, you use SHA-1, then you must prepare yourself to have to justify that choice. On the other hand, SHA-256 is a fine "default function" and nobody will question it.

There is no performance issue in PBKDF2 (PBKDF2 includes an "iteration count" meant to make it exactly as slow as needed) so there is very little reason to prefer SHA-1 over SHA-256 here. However, if you have an *existing*, deployed system which uses PBKDF2-with-SHA-1, then there is no immediate need to "fix" it.

Comment: There is also a pretty good explanation in [Stack Crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15218/is-pbkdf2-hmac-sha1-really-broken). In short, collisions for passwords are not a bad thing, it just means that a malicious user (or valid user) could log in with a couple of different passwords not that they can get back to the original "real" password.

Answer (score 1):

The attacks on SHA1 which caused a lot of public turmoil make it possible to construct a message which has the same hash as a different message. This is of course always possible (in principle) for every hash function, since a hash function has fewer output bits than input bits. However, it is normally not likely to happen by accident, and doing it on purpose should be computationally not feasible.

From a "ensure message integrity" point of view, this can be seen as a disaster.

On the other hand, for the purpose of generating random numbers, this has absolutely no bearing.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. SHA-256, or larger, might be more efficient if you want to generate more key material.
But PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA1 is fine. Also standard HMAC use has not been compromised, but again, longer hashes are in principle more secure in that scenario.