# How can I use authentication & authorization tags only for my Admin, in web.config without using Login controls in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm new in asp.net and I have a problem.
in my asp.net webdirectory I have some pages for users and an Admin Folder for administrator , I want to use some tags like authentication & authorization in my web.config File to determine my administrator username and password and determine only the admin can use pages in the admin folder but my problem is I did'nt use any login control in my web for my users to sign in.I use some textboxes which give the users information and then I connect to my table in database and check their information and I want to know how can I do that with this condition?
I'll become so thankfull if any body help me.
users Sign in with thier emails and passwords
this is my code:

```
       <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;Email :
        </td>
        <td class="style1">
            &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />

        </td>

    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="style1">
            &nbsp; <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                ErrorMessage="please enter your email!" 
                ControlToValidate="TextBox1" 
                Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="#CC0000" ValidationGroup="SignIn"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="incorrect format!" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"  Display="Dynamic"  ForeColor="#CC0000" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationGroup="SignIn"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
           <br />

        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;password:
        </td>
        <td class="style1">
            &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="Password" ></asp:TextBox>
           <br />
        </td>

    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="style1">
         &nbsp;
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter your password" ControlToValidate="TextBox2"  Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="#CC0000" ValidationGroup="SignIn" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="style1">
            &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="enter" 
                Width="123px" onclick="Button2_Click" ValidationGroup="SignIn" />
        </td>
```

> I have changed it:

```
    protected void Button2_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     if (Membership.ValidateUser(TextBox1.Text.Trim(), TextBox2.Text.Trim()))
    {
        if (Roles.IsUserInRole(TextBox1.Text.Trim(), "Admin"))
        {
            Response.Redirect("Admin/Default.aspx");
            Session["user"] = "admin";
        }
       // ad.Text = "admin";
    }
    else
    {
      int c = -1;
    SqlConnection cn2 = new SqlConnection();
    cn2.ConnectionString = "server = . ; database = mobile_store ; Trusted_Connection=true";
    DataTable tb = new  DataTable();

    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
    cmd2.Connection = cn2;
    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd2.CommandText = "Check_Email_Pass";
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mail", TextBox1.Text.Trim());
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", TextBox2.Text.Trim());
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@res", SqlDbType.Int);    
    cmd2.Parameters["@res"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
    da.Fill(tb);
    try
    {
        cn2.Open();
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        c = Convert.ToInt32(cmd2.Parameters["@res"].Value);

        switch (c)
        {
            case 1:
                {

                    Session["user"] = tb.Rows[0][0].ToString() + " " + tb.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                    Session["authenticate"] = true;
                    Session["id"] = Convert.ToInt32( tb.Rows[0][2]);

                    ((MasterPage)this.Master).lable2Visible = Session["user"].ToString();
                    Label2.Text = "Welcome" + " " + tb.Rows[0][0].ToString() + " " + tb.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                    TextBox1.Text = null;
                    if (Session["pagesource"] != null)
                    {
                        Response.Redirect((string)Session["pagesource"]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("~/user_page.aspx");
                    }

                }
                break;
            case 0:
                {
                    Label2.Text = "your password is wrong";

                }
                break;
            case 2:
                {

                    Label2.Text = "this email has registered before <br/> please sign up first";
                    TextBox3.Text = TextBox1.Text.Trim();
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

      }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = ex.ToString();

    }
    finally { cn2.Close(); }
   }
```

> in my web.config file

```
     <system.Web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms  timeout="20" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="AutoDetect" protection="All" requireSSL="false" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" loginUrl="entrance_before_paying.aspx" >
            <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
                <user name="elmiragolshanff@yahoo.com" password="elmira" />
            </credentials>
        </forms>
    </authentication>
    </system.web>     


        <location path="Admin">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="elmiragolshanff@yahoo.com" roles="Admin" />              
        </authorization>

</location>

    </system.web>
```

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text!**  Security is _hard_; do not re-invent the wheel.  You should use ASP.Net's built-in login system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it.now It works fine
web.configfile:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms  timeout="30" loginUrl="~/entrance_before_paying.aspx" defaultUrl="Admin/Default.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSDEMO"  cookieless="AutoDetect" protection="All"   >

        <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
                <user name="elmiragolshanff@yahoo.com"  password="elmira" />
            </credentials>
        </forms>
    </authentication>
```

my on button_click event in entrance_before_paying.aspx page :

```
if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(TextBox1.Text.Trim(), TextBox2.Text.Trim()))
   {

           Response.Redirect("Admin/Default.aspx");
            Session["user"] = "admin";     

   }
 else{ //I wrote the code to authenticate users ....}
```

Answer (score 1):

Elmira,

There's a few ways to accomplish this; @SLaks is right on his concern, though. Here's a post that may help you on this aspect, 'Hash and salt passwords in C#'.

[Hash and salt passwords in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138429/hash-and-salt-passwords-in-c-sharp)

That said, i think you would benefit from reading a bit about ASP.NET User Management: 'Managing Users by Using Membership'.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw292whz(v=vs.100).aspx

It will allow you to do exactly what you want - limit access to resources (pages) according to profiles.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but I don't have enough time to learn and change my codes and this is my College project so the security is not important for me.I have edited my codes but Its not work Is There any way, like something I wroted in my code to solve my problem?

Comment: I would then point you towards HTTP Module; it is often used for URL rewriting, and you can set a module to intercept all incoming requests. You can then evaluate user credentials and decide what to do accordingly.

Comment: ok thank you but can you tell me why Membership.ValidateUser(TextBox1.Text.Trim(), TextBox2.Text.Trim()) return false and what is the problem with my code?