# please tell me why this query not working

Tags: c#, authentication

I have in the DB Sid and password and it contain the Sid=senan and the password=pass1234
when I enter this details into my login screen always I get fail messagebox

```
SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter("select Count(*) from [user] where Sid=' " + textBox1.Text + " ' and password='" + textBox2.Text + "'", cnn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
cmd.Fill(dt);
if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
    MessageBox.Show("pass");
else
    MessageBox.Show("fail");
```

Comment: have you tried stepping through your code to see what values are being passed?

Comment: On a side-note - you really need to fix that terrible SQL-injection vulnerability.

Comment: @steve That's an answer, why not post it as such?

Comment: [Give me parameterized SQL, or give me death](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)

Comment: thank you all it's working, @Cylindric colud you tell me some tips to avoid sql injections

Comment: @SenanZedan the parameterized approach is the key to avoid Sql Injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error arises from a simple typo. You have spaces added to the value passed for the `Sid` condition.
However your query should be rewritten in this way

```
string cmdText = "select Count(*) from [user] where Sid=@sid and password=@pwd";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, cnn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", textBox2.Text);
int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
if (count > 0)
    MessageBox.Show("pass");
else
    MessageBox.Show("fail");
```

This approach uses a parameterized query to avoid [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work), and uses directly an SqlCommand without building the `SqlDataAdapter` and a `DataTable`. The [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) is the correct method to use when you need to retrieve simply the first column of a single row or call a scalar T-SQL function like `COUNT()`

As a side note, keep in mind that storing passwords in clear text in your database is a big security concern. Whoever has access to the database will be able to read the passwords of every user. The passwords should be [stored as a computed hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138429/hash-and-salt-passwords-in-c-sharp) and checked repeating the hashing algorithm on the user entered data.

Comment: thank you for all this information I will read how to use the hash to protect my passwords.