# Lifespan of hashed/salted passwords

Tags: c#, hash, passwords, salt

Whilst I understand the theology behind the *process* of salting and hashing a password, I don't quite understand the methodology. As far as I can tell, the methods listed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138429/hash-and-salt-passwords-in-c-sharp) and it's pertinent answers, as well as this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa545602(v=cs.70).aspx), all go through steps to create a salt of varying length to use in the process of hashing the password given.

However, what about checking the password at a later date? Creating the hash all over again will, as far as I can see, result in *an entirely new salt* being generated, ultimately causing validation to fail when an attempt is made to log in.

Am I missing where the salt or salt formula is saved? Or have I not quite understood the process?

Comment: When you hash a password along with a generated salt, you store the salt in plaintext somewhere

Comment: @72DFBF5BA0DF5BE9 So would I be correct in thinking those examples *do not* demonstrate that? Additionally, would it be equally as effective to hardcode a salt in a method that runs at the server?

Comment: Static single salt is not good, still it would slow down cracking process a lot, but not as good as dynamic salt per password. I didn't check those examples, but I know for sure that you store the username, passwordhash and salt in DB. When user re-enters the password, you append salt, hash it and check it.

Comment: @72DFBF5BA0DF5BE9 I see, so a salt is definitely only ever generated once per password?

Comment: Yes, make sure it's random each time for each new password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:

1. create **a new salt for each password** you want to hash
2. hash the password
3. **save as plain text both the hash and the salt**.

When you want to authenticate your user, you just have to compute the hash again with the salt you previously saved in your DB, then compare your hashes.

Here's [an excellent article](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) that explains the process in details. It also provides a [complete C# implementation](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#aspsourcecode).