# Decrypt MD5 Encrypted string in C#?

Tags: c#, encryption, passwords

I have used the following code to Encrypt a password using MD5 hashing.But I am stuck on how to decrypt the password . I am sure that it can be acheived easily without writing lot of code. Any help will be apprectiated.

```
 //Password encryption
    public string ComputePassword(string password)
    {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
            var md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            var md5data = md5.ComputeHash(bytes);

            for (int i = 0; i < md5data.Length; i++)
            {
                str.Append(md5data[i].ToString("x2"));
            }
            return str.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

How can I decrypt the above generated encrypted string

Comment: MD5 is "one-way" hash function. You can't  restore original value from hash.

Comment: Ok...then what is the alternative of md5 hash??

Comment: MD5 is not a very secure password hashing algorithm, see https://www.bentasker.co.uk/blog/security/201-why-you-should-be-asking-how-your-passwords-are-stored

Comment: @ksg - That depends on how secure you need the encryption.  Are you after very secure, or mainly obfuscation?

Comment: @Jaco can you suggest an algorithm??

Comment: @JerrenSaunders I am after obfuscation :{ )

Comment: @ksg: If these are user passwords then it's simple... *don't* "decrypt" them.  User passwords should be obscured with a 1-way hash and should *never* be retrievable.

Comment: @ksg Probably, you're on the wrong way, if we're talking about some user authentication. Usually it is not needed to decrypt password from hash. Instead you should compute hash of password entered by user and compare it with saved hash.

Comment: I'd suggest that you look into these pages for securing passwords:

https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#aspsourcecode
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa545602(v=cs.70).aspx  

If just after obfuscation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-and-decrypt-a-string/10366194#10366194

Comment: Thanks @AndyKorneyev for your suggestion.Sorry guys this was what I was looking for.

Comment: @ksg you can't just obfuscate passwords, most users tend to the same passwords across multiple systems. I would recommend to use BCrypt, there is a NuGet package for it, see https://bcrypt.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Jaco No no no. A single hash is far too quick to calculate. Passwords should be stored salted and run through an expensive key-stretching algorithm such as [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) or [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2).

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16857760) for PBKDF2 and [general advice](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523).