# Login C# WinForms using Dapper and Salt & Hash

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication, dapper

I'm making a WinForms application, but i'm not really sure if this is a good implementation for my Login Form.

This is the algorithm for **Salt Hash** i use, Thanks to [blowdart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138429/hash-and-salt-passwords-in-c-sharp):

```
private static byte[] CreateHash(byte[] bPassword, byte[] bSalt)
{
    HashAlgorithm algorithm = new SHA512Managed();
    byte[] bToBeHashed = new byte[bPassword.Length + bSalt.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < bPassword.Length; i++)
        bToBeHashed[i] = bPassword[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < bSalt.Length; i++)
        bToBeHashed[bPassword.Length + i] = bSalt[i];
    return algorithm.ComputeHash(bToBeHashed);
}
```

This is the method i call to access the data base (SQL Server):

```
public int Login(string strUser, string strPassword)
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GlobalConfig.ConnectionDataBaseString(db)))
    {
        byte[] bSalt = new byte[8];
        var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
        parameters.Add("@idUser", strUser);
        // dbo.spUserExists = SELECT byteSalt FROM users WHERE idUser=@idUser
        var reader = connection.ExecuteReader("dbo.spUserExists", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            bSalt = (byte[])reader["byteSalt"];
            byte[] bPassword = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strPassword); // string to byte[]
            byte[] bHash = new byte[bPassword.Length + bSalt.Length];
            bHash = CreateHash(bPassword, bSalt);
            parameters = new DynamicParameters();
            parameters.Add("@idUser", strUser);
            parameters.Add("@byteHash", bHash);
            reader.Dispose();
            reader.Close();
            // dbo.spPasswordExists = SELECT * FROM users WHERE idUser = @idUser AND byteHash = @byteHash
            var reader = connection.ExecuteReader("dbo.spPasswordExists", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            if (reader.Read())
                return 0; // User & Password are correct
            else
                return 2; // User correct, Password incorrect
        }
        else
            return 1; // User does not exists
    }
}
```

And this is the event when trying to Log In:

```
private void btnLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserTextBox.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please type your User.");
    }
    else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PasswordTextBox.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please type your Password.");
    }
    else
    {
        switch (Login(UserTextBox.Text, PasswordTextBox.Text))
        {
            case 0:
                if (RememberMeCheckBox.Checked)
                {
                    Properties.Settings.Default.UserName = UserTextBox.Text; // Remembers User name
                    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                }
                else
                {
                    Properties.Settings.Default.UserName = null;
                    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                }
                UserTextBox.Clear();
                PasswordTextBox.Clear();
                DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                this.Close();
                break;
            case 1:
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect User.");
                break;
            case 2:
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Password.");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

How can i improve this or make a better solution? Making sure that is a secure log in. Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you are trying to solve has already been addressed by Microsoft's own [ASP.NET Membership Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/membership-and-role-provider). Despite being branded as ASP.NET, it [can indeed be used](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3855.windows-forms-application-how-to-use-a-membership-provider-of-asp-net-in.aspx) in WinForms applications. The provider has its own set of database tables it uses for User and Role management. It also comes with a choice of pluggable password security features such as plaintext (yuck!), reversible encryption and hashing (which can be configured and overridden if you so desire).

To set it up you will need to add an entry to your app.config or configure it code-first. Either way [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.membership?view=netframework-4.8) should be a good start. Hopefully that will set you on right track.