# Encrypt password C#

Tags: c#, encryption

Im implementing users account in my website.I need to encrypt passwords from new members,however im getting crazy with many options that ive found to accomplish that.

Symmetric and asymmetric cryptosystems, public versus private keys, digital signatures, hash algorithms, RSA, DES, Rijndael, PGP, MD5, SHA-1, https, secure sockets, Camellia, IDEA; what does it all mean?

I dont even know the difference between MD5 and rinjdael,can somenone tell me the best option to encrypt?

Comment: here is a library for this: http://encrypto.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using asp.net, you can use the built in user account features.

If you insist on building your own, you shouldn't encrypt, you should hash and ONLY store the hash, not the actual password.

Here is a [link](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/creating-user-accounts-cs) to get you started.

**comment update**
[membership providers for MySql](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/mysqlmembershipprovider.aspx)
[membership providers for Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/dotnet/aspnet/index.html)

Comment: ive already seen that,a long time ago.This time i dont want to use ASP.NET account features,cause i going to use MYSQL,and ORACLE

Comment: I added links for membership providers to the dbms's you mentioned.

Comment: man i really appreciate your help,but i wont use ASP.NET features anyway.Thks for your help

Comment: @ozsenegal: You're doing it wrong. You should use off-the-shelf, proven code, not do it yourself. If you insist on doing it yourself, please publicize the fact that your site uses unproven security, written by developers who don't know one hash from another. You owe at least that much to your users. Or just take Lucas's advice and don't re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

[What is the easiest way to encrypt a password when I save it to the registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212510/c-what-is-the-easiest-way-to-encrypt-a-password-when-i-save-it-to-the-registry)

you dont encrypt passwords you hash them, see the link for a similar issue

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store passwords in a database for example, I would recommend you to use [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) (Hash-based Message Authentication Code); you'll need a cryptographic hash function (e.g. SHA-512) in combination with a secret key to generate the MAC. Also, it's important to note here that you don't encrypt the password, but you rather *hash* it.

For the encryption of locally saved passwords for example (though [Bruce Schneier says you should write your passwords down on paper](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/06/write_down_your.html)), you can use an asymmetric-key cryptosystem like [RSA](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA-Kryptosystem). In this case you'll have a key pair consisting of a public key, which you'll share with your friends, and a private key, which you should, well, keep private. The nice thing about RSA is that you can either encrypt messages with your public key and then decrypt them with your private key; or you can use it to digitally sign documents by using your private key to calculate the hash of a document, and then validate it using your public key. Pretty nifty!

Comment: If you use HMAC, what would you use for the key?  Salt?  If so, why not just salt the password and hash it yourself?

Comment: @Steven I'd use a randomly generated salt as the key. HMAC may be an overkill in this situation (`H(key1, H(key2 || message`), but it surely is stronger than a salted hash (`H(message || salt)`), i.e. HMAC is hardened against extension attacks for example.

Comment: Interesting. First, I'm used to seeing the salt come ahead of the message, which I believe would interfere with extension attacks. But I think that the main point of salting is to stop rainbow tables, not all possible attacks, so HMAC may indeed be a bit much. Then again, I don't see any great harm to using HMAC here, especially if it's iterated to strengthen it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't encrypt the password but take a hash of it using a salt (to protect against rainbow tables) and SHA-256 or better. This means you don't have to keep a secret key and worry about loads of key management stuff and also means that no one (including yourself) can find out a users password from the data in your database (they can only confirm that they have guessed the right password).

It is also suggested that you use a lot (1000+) of iterations of the hash to make it slow to calculate (not too slow for the user entering the correct password but far too slow if you're hashing loads of words to see if any match the contents of your db).

If you google salts, rainbow tables, hashes etc there is loads of information out there.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a really good article](http://www.aspheute.com/english/20040105.asp) that I used when I was first learning how to store passwords. This is a really good primer and it is written in C#

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered before, but the short version is that you salt the password, hash it with at least SHA-256, and preferably use strengthening.  If this doesn't make sense to you, you're not ready to write anything yet; keep researching.

Comment: This would be a fine opportunity to explain the otherwise inexplicable downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use MD5, it's simple to implement on .Net and it's a 128 bits (one way) cryptographic hash function. It has hash colission problems on wide ranges though.

Or you could check at Gost which is a 256 bits cryptographic hash function.

[GOST Hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOST_(hash_function))

Answer (score 0):

i have used this code to encrypt the password in binary format.. may be this will help you

```
private string Encrypt(string clearText)
{
    string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
    byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return clearText;
}
```

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.