# manage a secure password

Tags: c#, passwords, password-protection

My program asks for a password and save it inside a text file and the next time i run my program if the text file exists it asks for the password and I compare it with the password inside the text file.

Now, in the real world i know a text file is not used but I don't know how I can improve my technique 'cause regardless of a encryption algorithm a text file is readable for everyone and other solution as a registry key the same.

This is an exercise and my intention is to learn if I'm were programming a commercial app then what technique I should use to store a password with a more robust security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter where you store your passwords, as long as you store only a hash of them. A text file will do pretty well, important is that you use a salt and a slow hash function with a cost factor. Algorithms like MD5 or SHA* are not appropriate to hash passwords, because they are too fast and therefore can be brute-forced too easily.

The library [BCrypt.NET](https://bcrypt.codeplex.com/) implements the BCrypt algorithm, which is designed to hash passwords. It will automatically add a cryptographically safe salt and includes it in the resulting BCrypt hash.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
string hashToStoreInDb = BCrypt.HashPassword(password);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from existingHashFromDb.
bool isPasswordCorrect = BCrypt.Verify(password, existingHashFromDb);
```

Another good algorithm is PBKDF2, *crackstation.net* has a good [code example](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#aspsourcecode).

If you are interested in more detailed information, you could have a look at my tutorial about [safely storing passwords](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php).

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to encrypt or hash the password but never to decrypt it. I.e. you transform your password in a way which is not reversible.

- When the password is entered the first time, you (one way) encrypt
  the password and store it.
- When a user tries to login, the entered password is encrypted again and compared with the stored one.

A code example was already provided in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212510/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-encrypt-a-password-when-i-save-it-to-the-registry):

```
byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputString);
data = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(data);
String hash = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
```

Your program will store / compare the *hash* value instead of the plain password.

The code can and should be further approved. An attacker could create large dictionaries / rainbow tables of encrypted password and use them as a lookup for password cracking. This can be prevented by adding some "**salt**" to the password to be encrypted. Form more details see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212510/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-encrypt-a-password-when-i-save-it-to-the-registry).

Comment: Does this code salt the hash?! If not it's not really usable for passwords.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Thank you. Recommended "salt" in my answer and added a link for details.

Comment: Don't use `SHA256Managed` for this, use a real password hashing algorithm like PBKDF2 or BCrypt. Those hash in multiple iterations (usually 100s to 1000s)  to make it harder to bruteforce hashes.