# Encrypting a message using secret key in python

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, secret-key

I need to encrypt a message using a secret key and return the message. I tried this and I got the correct output.

```
def my_encryption(some_string):
    character_set= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 "
    secret_key="    Dd18Abz2EqNPW hYTOjBvtVlpXaH6msFUICg4o0KZwJeryQx3f9kSinRu5L7cGM"
    m=some_string
    k=m.translate({ord(x): y for (x, y) in zip(character_set,secret_key )})
    return m

print(my_encryption("Lets meet at the usual place at 9 am"))
```

The output I got is

```
oABjMWAABMDBMB2AMvjvDPMYPD1AMDBMGMDWB
```

and this is correct. I would like to know, will there be any other way to do this with out using translate?. I am curious to know the alternate ways. I will be glad to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a simple dictionary

```
def my_encryption(some_string):
    character_set= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 "
    secret_key=    "Dd18Abz2EqNPW hYTOjBvtVlpXaH6msFUICg4o0KZwJeryQx3f9kSinRu5L7cGM"
    table = {x: y for (x, y) in zip(character_set,secret_key )}
    return "".join( map(lambda x:table.get(x,x),some_string) )
```

the `get` method can receive 2 arguments, the first is the key to search and the second is a value to return in case that the key is not present, in this case assign that as `x` to leave that unchanged

here a test

```
>>> my_encryption("Lets meet at the usual place at 9 am")
'oABjMWAABMDBMB2AMvjvDPMYPD1AMDBMGMDW'
>>>
```

this is usually the first thing that come to my mind when I want to do this simple substitution cipher.

and the inverse is as simple as invert key-value

```
def my_decription(some_string):
    character_set= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 "
    secret_key=    "Dd18Abz2EqNPW hYTOjBvtVlpXaH6msFUICg4o0KZwJeryQx3f9kSinRu5L7cGM"
    table = {x: y for (x, y) in zip(character_set,secret_key )}
    return "".join( map(lambda x:table.get(x,x),some_string) )

>>> my_decription('oABjMWAABMDBMB2AMvjvDPMYPD1AMDBMGMDW')
'Lets meet at the usual place at 9 am'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution I use when making things less plain text is [base64](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/base64.html) module. This is not encryption by any means. Just makes the text a little harder to read:

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64encode(b'This is a secret.')
b'VGhpcyBpcyBhIHNlY3JldC4='
>>> base64.b64decode(b'VGhpcyBpcyBhIHNlY3JldC4=').decode('utf-8')
'This is a secret.'
```

Comment: no, if you observe the character set and secret key, a is mapped to D and b is mapped to d and so on.. with that character set only i would like to perform operations. i want to know the various ways other than usage of translate.

Comment: it is encrypting using the secret key above not just encrypting randomly.

Comment: Ah I see. Maybe this answer would be of some use? [Simple way to encode a string according to a password?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490334/simple-way-to-encode-a-string-according-to-a-password)

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_encryption(some_string):
     output_string=""
     index=0
     character_set = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 "
     secret_key    = "Dd18Abz2EqNPW hYTOjBvtVlpXaH6msFUICg4o0KZwJeryQx3f9kSinRu5L7cGM"
     for character in some_string:
        index=character_set.find(character)
        output_string=output_string+secret_key[index]
      return output_string
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post.