# Python encrypt/decrypt txt with a given password

Tags: python, encryption, pycrypto

I have a custom account manager. At the moment I store the whole information in a single txt document. I'm trying to figure out how to encrypt all the whole txt with a password introduced by user.

I've seen PyCrypto but I have so many problems because there must be everything 16-bytes multiple.

Can someone tell me how to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490334/simple-way-to-encode-a-string-according-to-a-password

Comment: I just have a big problem. I don't know how to convert the whole file in a 16-byte multiple string.

Comment: Look into bcrypt at http://bcrypt.sourceforge.net/ it is a command line program that you can execute via os.system() and it will ask the user to type in the password both when encrypting and decrypting.

Comment: @Marichyasana I'll take a look at this. There is any remove script in case it doesn't suit my necessities?

Comment: Crypto is not an area for amateurs.  Amateurs will make mistakes, and will lay themselves open to being sued when their security is broken.  Get a professional to do the job.  Yes, this means employing an expert.

Comment: @rossum I've finally found a solution with simplecrypt

Comment: @Lechucico It is a stand alone program, nothing to install/de-install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this as solution:

```
from simplecrypt import encrypt, decrypt
ciphertext = encrypt('password', plaintext)
plaintext = decrypt('password', ciphertext)
```