# How do I prevent url query tampering using flask request.args.get?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a url `http://localhost:8000/savings?sv=30`

In Flask I retrieve the value using Jinja templates to display the value of `sv` on the screen:

```
{% set sv = request.args.get('sv', '') %}

<p>{{ sv }}</p>
```

Is it possible to prevent a user from editing the url to display a different value?

Comment: Short answer: no. HTTP clients are free to send whatever they want in the url. Now if you explained your _real_ use case ([xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) anyone ?), then perhaps someone could pint you to the proper solution ;-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone else wondering I have decided to use encode/decode to obscure the value of `sv` from users.

I have taken Martijn Pieter's advice to obscure the value as opposed to encrypting the value: [Simple way to encode a string according to a password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490334/simple-way-to-encode-a-string-according-to-a-password/55147077#55147077)

```
import zlib
from base64 import urlsafe_b64encode as b64e, urlsafe_b64decode as b64d

def obscure(data: bytes) -> bytes:
    return b64e(zlib.compress(data, 9))

def unobscure(obscured: bytes) -> bytes:
    return zlib.decompress(b64d(obscured))
```

where this link is sent to a user:

```
        link = 'https://localhost:8000/savings?sv=' + bytes.decode(obscure(str.encode(amount)))
```

Which is then decoded when they click the link:

```
@onboard.route('/savings', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def savings():
    savings = request.args.get('sv')
    savings = str.encode(savings)
    savings = unobscure(savings)
    savings = bytes.decode(savings)
    return render_template('onboard/savings.html', savings=savings)
```