# I need to store passwords in config encrypted as password

Tags: python, encryption, encode, password-encryption, encryption-symmetric

I am using Python 3
I have an Auth_INI ConfigParser file with usernames mapped to passwords.
I need to *encrypt* the password *with the password* so only the password can *decrypt* it.

```
> Auth_INI = ConfigParser()
> password = 'password'
> password_encrypted = encrypt(password,'password') 
> Auth_INI['username'] = password_encrypted
```

All it needs to be is somekind of difficult hash/unhash encoding perhaps. I do not require anything
too fancy. No keyrings, just plain text encoded/unencoded.

With this encryption scheme I can easily verify a person by `decrypt(password,'guessword') != 'guessword'` and there is no reason to do anything more than this.

Is anyone able to recommend an encryption/Encoding library that works like this?

Right now I am just using urlsafe_b64encode('password') and there is no password to decode the password so essentially there is no encryption for the password. Please do help...

Comment: Encrypting a password with a password is like dog chasing its own tail.

Answer (score 1):

From the [PyNaCl](https://pynacl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/password_hashing/) documentation, here's a quick and dirty example:

```py
import nacl.pwhash

# Password used to hash itself
orig_password = b'my password'

# Hashing the password
hashed_data = nacl.pwhash.str(orig_password)

# The result will be True on password match.
res = nacl.pwhash.verify(hashed_data, orig_password)
print(res)

# On mismatch an exception will be raised
wrong_password = b'My password'
res2 = nacl.pwhash.verify(hashed_data, wrong_password)
```

Comment: found an easy answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66728699/15627277