# How to generate an encoding key from a string? - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, decoding

I am creating myself a password saver in which I could enter my passwords and it would be securely stored, like 1Password. Once you enter, you must enter/create yourself a password and I would like it to encode the saved passwords using this one. How can I do so?

Help is appreciated :)

Comment: asfar as I understud using hashlib you dont save plain password you use an hashing alghoritm (i.e hashlib.sha256). Once hashed you won't be able to recover the password, but you can compare the digest of the hashed pasword with the one suplied by the use if they match the password obtasined is the good one to access your datanase or whatsoever as per your question see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490334/simple-way-to-encode-a-string-according-to-a-password

Comment: youe question title is kind of misleading

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple way to encode a string according to a password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490334/simple-way-to-encode-a-string-according-to-a-password)

Comment: Unlike Encryption and Hashing, Encoding is not used for security purpose. Fundamentally, it is just a technique to transform data into other formats so that it can be consumed by numerous systems. There is no use of keys in encoding. The algorithm that is used to encode the data is used to decode it as well.

Comment: Key encoding is the process of converting encryption and decryption keys, or private and public keys, into a specific encoding format for storing them in files or transmitting them to remote systems.  --->so I suspect it depends on your encryption system ?