# Do I need to include -n option when encoding a password using base64?

Tags: base64, passwords

I read somewhere that when encoding a password in base64, I should use `echo -n` to prevent the newline from being included in the encoded value.  For example,

```
echo changeme | base64
Y2hhbmdlbWUK
echo -n changeme | base64
Y2hhbmdlbWU=
```

These two base64 strings are different, but when I decode them they are the same

```
echo Y2hhbmdlbWUK | base64 -d
changeme
echo Y2hhbmdlbWU= | base64 -d
changeme
```

So do I really need to add the `-n` option `https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo` says:

> do not output the trailing newline

Searches gave this long winded example using python... didn't read it all [Simple way to encode a string according to a password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490334/simple-way-to-encode-a-string-according-to-a-password)

Comment: The decoded ones *look* the same because you're not seeing the trailing newline… but it's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use an [online converter](https://base64.guru/converter/decode/hex) to decode it to hex, you'll see that the first string becomes `6368616e67656d650a` and has `0a` (ASCII Linefeed) on the end, which the second doesn't have.

**So the answer is yes, you really need to add the -n option.**

If you change your `echo` to `echo -n` you'll see this as well.

```
echo -n Y2hhbmdlbWU= | base64 -d
changemePROMPT-SHOWS-HERE
```

Another way to see this is using the following UNIX command:

```
echo -n Y2hhbmdlbWUK | base64 -d | od -c
0000000   c   h   a   n   g   e   m   e  \n

echo -n Y2hhbmdlbWU= | base64 -d | od -c
0000000   c   h   a   n   g   e   m   e
```

Where you can see the first encoding includes the linefeed and the second does not.

Comment: Very cool.  Base64 guru website that you've linked to: https://base64.guru/converter/decode/hex

Comment: esp. the to hex function is useful to see binary/unprinatable content, but for other use cases, there are many other useful converters.