# asynchronous python encrption using a user-set password using python cryptography

Tags: python, asynchronous, encryption, cryptography, passwords

a while back i asked a question about cryptography using a user-set password : [Proper data encryption with a user-set password in python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73532164/proper-data-encryption-with-a-user-set-password-in-python3)
and now i am working on something which requires async stuff so my question is
that is there any alternative or anything to python cryptography that i could use that supports asynchronous stuff

currently im thinking of spawning another thread or process or something, im not sure yet, but im hoping theres *something*

cheers

Comment: Async does not make much sens in context of cryptography, because crypto operations do not wait for a network or disk task, instead the use the CPU to perform certain cryptographic operations. Thus implementing crypto as async operations would not have a significant impact as the CPU would be blocked in any way.If you want to speed-up cryptography use multiple threads.