# C++ XOR key is too long?

Tags: c++, xor

I have a XOR key (dfficvvifvdfher89429338jwesjcnasidneufhrfdfha23p3rwe23323ncdnhj) but it seems to be way too long, even for *long long* format.

How can I use this key and get rid of "error C2177: constant too big"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put each value into a distinct char in a char array, i.e.:

```
const char xor_key[] = "dffic...";
```

You then XOR however-many characters against the key at a time, then use the key again at the next character after that.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think it would be that easy! :P

Comment: That's what the cracker said when he decrypted the message.

Comment: i.e. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135186/whats-wrong-with-xor-encryption