# Encrypt in c# and decrypt in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#

I create in c# a string which is saved into a html. In some input-fields I want to "hide" some strings which should be decrypt via JavaScript implemented in the html.

In C# (encrypt)

```
    public static string Crypt(string text, string k = "xyz")
    {
        var result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int c = 0; c < text.Length; c++)
            result.Append((char)((UInt16)text[c] ^ (UInt16)k[c % k.Length]));
        return result.ToString();
    }
```

In JavaScript (decrypt)

```
        function crypt(input, key = "xyz") 
        {
            let result = '';
            for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                let charCode = input.charCodeAt(i) ^ key.charCodeAt(i % key.length);
                result += String.fromCharCode(charCode);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

The decryption mostly works fine, but some words failed (samples in German)
erpiesen (instead of erwiesen), lässs (instead of lässt), bepegen (instead of gewesen)

Even long words works fine (for instance: usammengestellt, verbrennen, beginnen ...).

Any idea or recommandation for an easy way to make words "unreadable" in c# and readable again in JavaScript?

Comment: XOR encryption is completely breakable https://stackoverflow.com/a/1135197/14868997 Other than "you can't see at a glance what the data is", it's not actually encrypted. Use proper encryption, with TLS, to communicate between server and client.