# Can I put a + sign in a folder with IIS?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iis, url-rewriting, url-routing

I'm pretty sure this can't be done, but I'm looking for a hack or way to put a + in a folder name, like

http://www.mysite.com/cats+dogs/Default.aspx

I'm using IIS 7, and have tried creating a virtual directory to achieve this, and it didn't work. I am not allowed to put %2B in the explorer folder or virtual folder name.

Any ideas how I could hack this to make it work? We've already had brochures printed up with a url on it, and wondering if there is some way I can alias it or some trick that might do it.

EDIT: I was able to figure this out, by creating a virtual folder with a + in it, then redirecting to a URL, which points to a virtual directory with the content.

Comment: "We've already had brochures printed up with a url on it" - Ooops!!

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3375789/12484

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have some luck with doing a url-rewrite. This can be done very easily in the web.config or with an httpmodule.

Looks like you will still need to use a space or the IIS fix mentioned below for your + character issue, but for some flexibility in the future you can always include URL rewrites for mapping urls to files.

```
  <httpModules>
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </httpModules>

  <rewriter>
    <rewrite url="~/cats dogs/Default.aspx" to="~/MyRealFile.aspx" />
  </rewriter>
```

Answer (score 7):

[IIS 7.0 Breaking changes for ASP.NET 2.0 applications in Integrated Mode](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/12/08/IIS-7.0-Breaking-Changes-ASP.NET-2.0-applications-Integrated-mode.aspx)

Here's the relevant excerpt from the page, which shows the workaround/fix.

> Request limits and URL processing The
>   following changes result due to
>   additional restrictions on how IIS
>   processes incoming requests and their
>   URLs.
>
> 11) Request URLs containing unencoded
>   “+” characters in the path (not
>   querystring) is rejected by default
>
> You will receive HTTP Error 404.11 –
>   Not Found: The request filtering
>   module is configured to deny a request
>   that contains a double escape
>   sequence.
>
> This error occurs because IIS is by
>   default configured to reject attempts
>   to doubly-encode a URL, which commonly
>   represent an attempt to execute a
>   canonicalization attack.
>
> Workaround:
>
> 1) Applications that require the use
>   of the “+” character in the URL path
>   can disable this validation by setting
>   the allowDoubleEscaping attribute in
>   the
>   system.webServer/security/requestFiltering
>   configuration section in the
>   application’s web.config.  However,
>   this may make your application more
>   vulnerable to malicious URLs:
>
> ```
> <system.webServer> 
>     <security> 
>             <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" /> 
>     </security> 
> </system.webServer>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Just put a space in the folder name: "cats dogs".

The space character is encoded using the plus character, so when the server sees the plus character, it will get the folder with the space in it.

Comment: This is how it used to be, but it doesn't work in most modern browsers and default IIS settings.