# Plus (+) in MVC Argument causes 404 on IIS 7.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, arguments, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an MVC route that is giving me hell on a staging server running IIS.  I am running Visual Studio 2010's development server locally.

Here is a sample URL that actually works on my dev box:

```
Root/CPUBoards/Full+Size

Results
Server Error404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

Here is the complete behaviour I am seeing.

Localhost:

```
Root/CPUBoards/Full Size - Resolves
Root/CPUBoards/Full%20Size - Resolves
Root/CPUBoards/Full+Size - Resolves
```

Staging Server with IIS 7.0:

```
Root/CPUBoards/Full Size - Resolves
Root/CPUBoards/Full%20Size - Resolves
Root/CPUBoards/Full+Size - 404 Not Found Error.
```

Any ideas?  I need to work with the encoded version for several reasons... won't waste your time with them.

HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Full Size") returns the version with the plus sing... Full+Size.  This works on my dev box, but not on the staging server.  I would prefer to just get it working on the server, since I already have everything else tested and working locally, but I have no idea where to start looking on the server configuration to get it to behave the same way.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you build locally using IIS 7 instead of the ASP.NET development environment?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`+` only has the special meaning of being a space in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data such as the query string part of a URL.

In other parts of the URL like path components, `+` literally means a plus sign. So resolving `Full+Size` to the unencoded name `Full Size` should not work anywhere.

The only correct form of a space in a path component is `%20`. (It still works when you type an actual space because the browser spots the error and corrects it for you.) `%20` also works in form-URL-encoded data as well, so it's generally safest to always use that.

Sadly `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` is misleadingly-named. It produces `+` in its output instead of `%20`, so it's really a form-URL-encoder and not a standard URL-encoder. Unfortunately I don't know of an ASP.NET function to “really URL-encode” strings for use in a path, so all I can recommend is doing a string replace of `+` to `%20` after encoding.

Alternatively, avoid using spaces in path parts, eg. by replacing them with `-`. It's common to ‘slug’ titles being inserted to URLs, reducing them to simple alphanumerics and ‘safe’ punctuation, to avoid filling the URL with ugly `%nn` sequences.

Comment: OK.  This is very helpful.  These URL "Segments" are coming from a database, and we prefer to allow the data in the database to be natural.  We also need the URL to be unique, so replacing a bunch of stuff with '-' is not desireable.  For example, we have both underscore and space characters, both of which people like to replace with a dash.  I suppose this means we are stuck using "ugliness" like %20 to represent characters accurately, but these are the edge cases, and the compromise is not so bad.  I guess I will have to do some manual replacing before URL Encoding stuff.  Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately you can't *quite* get arbitrary strings into path parts. `%2F` (the encoded form of `/`) is blocked by many web servers—by default in Apache, and unavoidably in IIS. IIS also blocks `%5C`, and all servers block `%00` (other control codes can also cause various difficulties, and of course Unicode in path parts has some gotchas of its own).

Answer (score 23):

This is an IIS security setting. There is a standard request filter that rejects URLs containing + (plus) characters.

You can disable it for your web, adding this to your web.config:

```
<configuration>
   ...
   <system.webServer>
      ...
      <security>
          <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: Works for me. More details about 'allowDoubleEscaping' here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1453287/3678079

Answer (score 4):

`System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(string str)` encodes a `+` to a `%20`

Comment: I think the OP has that part figured out - why it's causing the error is more the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with @bobince, the problem is in the wrong encoding to %2b instead of %20

> Sadly HttpUtility.UrlEncode is misleadingly-named. It produces + in its output instead of %20, so it's really a form-URL-encoder and not a standard URL-encoder. Unfortunately I don't know of an ASP.NET function to “really URL-encode” strings for use in a path, so all I can recommend is doing a string replace of + to %20 after encoding.

this is the important part, which is to replace the + sign with %20