# Rijndal Algorithm using C#

Tags: c#, cryptography, encryption, rijndael

I want the code of Rijndael algorithm to encrypt any given text to store it in a database, I also want to know how to reverse the encryption method, ie: decrypt the encrypted text to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an existing .NET Framework [implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx) already.

Comment: +1 Why reinvent the wheel? (unless the goal itself is to do it yourself exercise)

Comment: Yes. You can use the implementation in any application that can use .NET framework libraries (Websites, console, windows forms, wpf, silverlight etc)

Answer (score 4):

This resource has what you need:

http://www.obviex.com/samples/Encryption.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165808/simple-2-way-encryption-for-c/212707#212707) by [Mark Brittingham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15592/mark-brittingham). This class both includes encryption and decryption methods.