# Modular multiplicative inverse function in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

Does some standard Python module contain a function to compute [modular multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of a number, i.e. a number `y = invmod(x, p)` such that `x*y == 1 (mod p)`? Google doesn't seem to give any good hints on this.

Of course, one can come up with home-brewed 10-liner of [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), but why reinvent the wheel.

For example, Java's `BigInteger` has `modInverse` method. Doesn't Python have something similar?

Comment: In Python 3.8 (due to be released later this year), you'll be able to use the built-in `pow` function for this: `y = pow(x, -1, p)`. See https://bugs.python.org/issue36027. It only took 8.5 years from the question being asked to a solution appearing in the standard library!

Comment: I see @MarkDickinson modestly neglected to mention that ey is the author of this very useful enhancement, so I will.  Thanks for this work, Mark, it looks great!

Answer (score 239):

#### Python 3.8+

```
y = pow(x, -1, p)
```

#### Python 3.7 and earlier

Maybe someone will find this useful (from [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Mathematics/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)):

```
def egcd(a, b):
    if a == 0:
        return (b, 0, 1)
    else:
        g, y, x = egcd(b % a, a)
        return (g, x - (b // a) * y, y)

def modinv(a, m):
    g, x, y = egcd(a, m)
    if g != 1:
        raise Exception('modular inverse does not exist')
    else:
        return x % m
```

Comment: I was having problems with negative numbers using this algorithm. modinv(-3, 11) didn't work. I fixed it by replacing egcd with the implementation on page two of this pdf: http://anh.cs.luc.edu/331/notes/xgcd.pdf Hope that helps!

Comment: @Qaz You can also just reduce -3 modulo 11 to make it positive, in this case modinv(-3, 11) == modinv(-3 + 11, 11) == modinv(8, 11). That's probably what the algorithm in your PDF happens to do at some point.

Comment: If you happen to be using `sympy`, then `x, _, g = sympy.numbers.igcdex(a, m)` does the trick.

Comment: Love that it's baked into the language for 3.8+

Answer (score 67):

If your modulus is prime (you call it `p`) then you may simply compute:

```
y = x**(p-2) mod p  # Pseudocode
```

Or in Python proper:

```
y = pow(x, p-2, p)
```

Here is someone who has implemented some number theory capabilities in Python: http://www.math.umbc.edu/~campbell/Computers/Python/numbthy.html

Here is an example done at the prompt:

```
m = 1000000007
x = 1234567
y = pow(x,m-2,m)
y
989145189L
x*y
1221166008548163L
x*y % m
1L
```

Comment: Naive exponentiation is not an option because of time (and memory) limit for any reasonably big value of p like say 1000000007.

Comment: modular exponentiation is done with at most N*2 multiplications where N is the number of bits in the exponent. using a modulus of 2**63-1 the inverse can be computed at the prompt and returns a result immediately.

Comment: Wow, awesome. I'm aware of quick exponentiation, I just wasn't aware that pow() function can take third argument which turns it into modular exponentiation.

Comment: for large primes, using the egcd method in python is actually faster than using pow(a, m-2, m) ....

Comment: By the way this works because from Fermat little theorem pow(x,m-1,m) must be 1. Hence (pow(x,m-2,m) * x) % m  == 1.  So pow(x,m-2,m)  is the inverse of x (mod m).

Answer (score 25):

You might also want to look at the [gmpy](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/) module. It is an interface between Python and the GMP multiple-precision library. gmpy provides an invert function that does exactly what you need:

```
>>> import gmpy
>>> gmpy.invert(1234567, 1000000007)
mpz(989145189)
```

**Updated answer**

As noted by @hyh , the `gmpy.invert()` returns 0 if the inverse does not exist. That matches the behavior of GMP's `mpz_invert()` function. `gmpy.divm(a, b, m)` provides a general solution to `a=bx (mod m)`.

```
>>> gmpy.divm(1, 1234567, 1000000007)
mpz(989145189)
>>> gmpy.divm(1, 0, 5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: not invertible
>>> gmpy.divm(1, 4, 8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: not invertible
>>> gmpy.divm(1, 4, 9)
mpz(7)
```

`divm()` will return a solution when `gcd(b,m) == 1` and raises an exception when the multiplicative inverse does not exist.

Disclaimer: I'm the current maintainer of the gmpy library.

**Updated answer 2**

gmpy2 now properly raises an exception when the inverse does not exists:

```
>>> import gmpy2

>>> gmpy2.invert(0,5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: invert() no inverse exists
```

Comment: This is cool until I found `gmpy.invert(0,5) = mpz(0)` instead of raising an error...

Comment: @hyh Can you report this as an issue at gmpy's home page? It's always appreciated if issues are reported.

Comment: BTW, is there a modular multiplication in this `gmpy` package? (i.e. some function that has the same value but is faster than `(a * b)% p` ?)

Comment: It has been proposed before and I am experimenting with different methods. The simplest approach of just calculating `(a * b) % p` in a function isn't faster than just evaluating `(a * b) % p` in Python. The overhead for a function call is greater than the cost of evaluating the expression. See https://code.google.com/p/gmpy/issues/detail?id=61 for more details.

Comment: I see. (Actually in lots of situation, e.g. finite field arithmetic, the modulos is fixed. I hope there is a way to set an environment variable, `p` such that all arithmetic is then done modulo `p`. Maybe that needs some bottom up design instead of a few lines of scripts.)

Comment: That is one of the options. Actually, I'm working on a re-design to provide better support for threading. After that is done, it will be easy to add a modulus option to context.

Comment: The great thing is that this also works for non-prime modulii.

Answer (score 21):

As of 3.8 pythons pow() function can take a modulus and a negative integer. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow). Their case for how to use it is

```
>>> pow(38, -1, 97)
23
>>> 23 * 38 % 97 == 1
True
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is a one-liner for [CodeFights](https://codefights.com/feed/oJoQuXaP2uT2gPjyM); it is one of the shortest solutions:

```
MMI = lambda A, n,s=1,t=0,N=0: (n < 2 and t%N or MMI(n, A%n, t, s-A//n*t, N or n),-1)[n<1]
```

It will return `-1` if `A` has no multiplicative inverse in `n`.

Usage:

```
MMI(23, 99) # returns 56
MMI(18, 24) # return -1
```

The solution uses the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

Answer (score 9):

[Sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html), a python module for symbolic mathematics, has a built-in modular inverse function if you don't want to implement your own (or if you're using Sympy already):

```
from sympy import mod_inverse

mod_inverse(11, 35) # returns 16
mod_inverse(15, 35) # raises ValueError: 'inverse of 15 (mod 35) does not exist'
```

This doesn't seem to be documented on the Sympy website, but here's the docstring: [Sympy mod_inverse docstring on Github](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/eefc3cff6dd44588b88a12e0a532c9ddb0197ab4/sympy/core/numbers.py#L441)

Comment: `mod_inverse` is documented on sympy's website: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.numbers.mod_inverse

Answer (score 5):

Here is a concise 1-liner that does it, without using any external libraries.

```
# Given 0<a<b, returns the unique c such that 0<c<b and a*c == gcd(a,b) (mod b).
# In particular, if a,b are relatively prime, returns the inverse of a modulo b.
def invmod(a,b): return 0 if a==0 else 1 if b%a==0 else b - invmod(b%a,a)*b//a
```

Note that this is really just egcd, streamlined to return only the single coefficient of interest.

Answer (score 3):

I try different solutions from this thread and in the end I use this one:

```
def egcd(a, b):
    lastremainder, remainder = abs(a), abs(b)
    x, lastx, y, lasty = 0, 1, 1, 0
    while remainder:
        lastremainder, (quotient, remainder) = remainder, divmod(lastremainder, remainder)
        x, lastx = lastx - quotient*x, x
        y, lasty = lasty - quotient*y, y
    return lastremainder, lastx * (-1 if a < 0 else 1), lasty * (-1 if b < 0 else 1)


def modinv(a, m):
    g, x, y = self.egcd(a, m)
    if g != 1:
        raise ValueError('modinv for {} does not exist'.format(a))
    return x % m
```

[Modular_inverse in Python](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Modular_inverse#Python)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code, it might be sloppy but it seems to work for me anyway.

```
# a is the number you want the inverse for
# b is the modulus

def mod_inverse(a, b):
    r = -1
    B = b
    A = a
    eq_set = []
    full_set = []
    mod_set = []

    #euclid's algorithm
    while r!=1 and r!=0:
        r = b%a
        q = b//a
        eq_set = [r, b, a, q*-1]
        b = a
        a = r
        full_set.append(eq_set)

    for i in range(0, 4):
        mod_set.append(full_set[-1][i])

    mod_set.insert(2, 1)
    counter = 0

    #extended euclid's algorithm
    for i in range(1, len(full_set)):
        if counter%2 == 0:
            mod_set[2] = full_set[-1*(i+1)][3]*mod_set[4]+mod_set[2]
            mod_set[3] = full_set[-1*(i+1)][1]

        elif counter%2 != 0:
            mod_set[4] = full_set[-1*(i+1)][3]*mod_set[2]+mod_set[4]
            mod_set[1] = full_set[-1*(i+1)][1]

        counter += 1

    if mod_set[3] == B:
        return mod_set[2]%B
    return mod_set[4]%B
```

Answer (score 2):

The code above will not run in python3 and is less efficient compared to the GCD variants. However, this code is very transparent. It triggered me to create a more compact version:

```
def imod(a, n):
 c = 1
 while (c % a > 0):
     c += n
 return c // a
```

Comment: This is OK to explain it to kids, and when `n == 7`. But  otherwise it's about equivalent of this "algorithm": `for i in range(2, n): if i * a % n == 1: return i`

Answer (score 2):

from the cpython implementation [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/196a530e00d88a138973bf9182e013937e293f97/Objects/longobject.c#L4178):

```
def invmod(a, n):
    b, c = 1, 0
    while n:
        q, r = divmod(a, n)
        a, b, c, n = n, c, b - q*c, r
    # at this point a is the gcd of the original inputs
    if a == 1:
        return b
    raise ValueError("Not invertible")
```

according to the comment above this code, it can return small negative values, so you could potentially check if negative and add n when negative before returning b.

Comment: "so you could potentially check if negative and add n when negative before returning b".  Unfortunately n is 0 at that point.  (You'd have to save, and use, the original value of n.)

Comment: @DonHatch agreed

Answer (score 1):

To figure out the modular multiplicative inverse I recommend using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm like this:

```
def multiplicative_inverse(a, b):
    origA = a
    X = 0
    prevX = 1
    Y = 1
    prevY = 0
    while b != 0:
        temp = b
        quotient = a/b
        b = a%b
        a = temp
        temp = X
        a = prevX - quotient * X
        prevX = temp
        temp = Y
        Y = prevY - quotient * Y
        prevY = temp

    return origA + prevY
```

Comment: There appears to be a bug in this code: `a = prevX - quotient * X` should be `X = prevX - quotient * X`, and it should return `prevX`. FWIW, this implementation is similar to that in [Qaz's link](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/331/notes/xgcd.pdf) in the comment to Märt Bakhoff's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's a function in C which you can easily convert to python. In the below c function extended euclidian algorithm is used to calculate inverse mod.

```
int imod(int a,int n){
int c,i=1;
while(1){
    c = n * i + 1;
    if(c%a==0){
        c = c/a;
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
return c;}
```

Translates to Python Function

```
def imod(a,n):
  i=1
  while True:
    c = n * i + 1;
    if(c%a==0):
      c = c/a
      break;
    i = i+1
  
  return c
```

Reference to the above C function is taken from the following link [C program to find Modular Multiplicative Inverse of two Relatively Prime Numbers](http://www.psychocodes.in/c-program-to-find-modular-multiplicative-inverse-of-two-relatively-prime-numbers.html)