# generating serialized rsa public / private keys from N E D Big Ints

Tags: javascript, python, ssh, pseudocode

We're generating rsa keys, and would like to store them as public and private base64 hashes, like I'm used to seeing in my ~/.ssh folder on my linux box.

However, we're dealing with the RSA primitives - the n, e, and d values.

How do I generate the base64 hashes out of those values? And vice versa (if it's not obvious).

Comment: Why not http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/base64.html and/or (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rsa http://stuvel.eu/rsa) ?

Comment: @J.Random any answers?

Answer (score 2):

base64 is an encoding scheme for binary data represented as text, not a hashing algorithm. If you are referring to the fingerprint, it is MD5.

For both the fingerprint and the base64-encoded data, you can consult or even reuse [Twisted's Conch implementation](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-10.0.0/twisted/conch/ssh/keys.py#L583).

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the right ASN.1 encoding and then base64.

unfortunately, i have no idea what the right ASN.1 encoding is (i don't really understand ASN.1 myself).  it's built in to openssl, but i can't find a way to access it from the command line.  you can write it from C using http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_print.html and http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/rsa.html

you have python in the tags.  pyopenssl wraps openssl and might provide an easier path - https://code.launchpad.net/pyopenssl - but looking at the source it seems like they're too high level (they don't seem to expose the RSA struct).

if you speak ASN.1 (or have a library that does so, like http://pyasn1.sourceforge.net/) then this might be all you need - https://polarssl.org/kb/cryptography/asn1-key-structures-in-der-and-pem

(i realise this is rather incomplete - i'm not looking for the bounty, just dumping what i know in case it's enough to help - basically "ASN.1 for DER" is the bit you're missing; it's what defines the structure so that the different parts can be separated out when read back)

Comment: The public key id_rsa.pub has a different format however, see my answer (it'll be updated with details).

Answer (score 1):

I'll update this with more details and a decoder when I get free in a few hours.

```
def bitlength_and_integer_in_bytes(n):
    bytes_length = n.bit_length()//8+1
    return bytes_length.to_bytes(4, "big")+n.to_bytes(bytes_length, "big")

def gen_id_rsa_pub(n,e):
    return b"ssh-rsa "+base64.b64encode(b"\x00\x00\x00\x07ssh-rsa"+bitlength_and_integer_in_bytes(e)+bitlength_and_integer_in_bytes(n))+b" RSA key description"
open("id_rsa.pub", "bw").write(gen_id_rsa_pub(n,e))
##import base64
##from pyasn1.codec.der import decoder
##s = "\n".join(open(".ssh/id_rsa").readlines()[1:-1])
##d = decoder.decode(base64.b64decode(s))
import base64
from pyasn1.codec.der import encoder
from pyasn1.type.univ import *
#below from http://stackoverflow.com/a/9758173/443348
def egcd(a, b):
    if a == 0:
        return (b, 0, 1)
    else:
        g, y, x = egcd(b % a, a)
        return (g, x - (b // a) * y, y)

def modinv(a, m):
    g, x, y = egcd(a, m)
    if g != 1:
        raise Exception('modular inverse does not exist')
    else:
        return x % m

#got example values from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm)#A_working_example
p = 61
q = 53
n = p*q #3233
totient_n = (p-1)*(q-1) # 3120
e = 17 # Should be coprime to 3120
d = modinv(e, totient_n) #2753

s = Sequence()
def setvalues(sequence, values):
    for index, value in enumerate(values):
        sequence.setComponentByPosition(index, value)

q = n/p

setvalues(s, map(Integer, (0, n, e, d, p, q, d%(p-1), d%(q-1), modinv(q,p))))
id_rsa = b"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"+base64.b64encode(encoder.encode(s))+b"\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
open("id_rsa", "bw").write(id_rsa)
```