# Negative power in modular pow()

Tags: python, math, modulo, pow

How can we use `pow` with a negative exponent in a modular context?

> pow(x, y, [z])
>   If z is present, x and y must be of integer types, and y must be non-negative.

```
>>> pow(11444, -357)
0.0
>>> pow(11444, -357) % 48731
0.0
>>> pow(11444, -357, 48731)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: pow() 2nd argument cannot be negative when 3rd argument specified
```

In my use case, I want to encrypt a message using a Schnorr scheme:

```
y = (g ** -w) mod p
```

but `pow` won't accept a negative number as the second argument here.  As an example, from

```
g = 11444
p = 48731
w = 357
```

`y` should be `7355`.

Comment: Sorry, what? Do you have an actual question, preferably with an [mcve] for us so we can provide an answer to it?

Comment: `pow(10, -2)` produces `0.01`, for example, so your statement that *python won't work with negative number* is at the very least a misunderstanding on your part.

Comment: I think what he means is that the lacking precision for very small numbers will yield a `0.0`.

Comment: I think what the OP is really wondering is "does Python automatically compute the modular multiplicative inverse to support taking negative modular powers?" and the answer is no.  g^-1 mod p is 29420, and `pow(29420, 357, 48731) == 7355`; you need to compute 29420 yourself (e.g. using the extended Euclidean method.)

Comment: Thanks @DSM, But I'm not answer "does it" nor "How". At least will read for extended Euclidean method you advised.

Comment: @DSM: I've reopened this after an edit by the OP, but your explanation is a lot better. You could edit that into the question perhaps.

Comment: I think that pretty fine to close question. If @DSM wants, I can toggle his answer as right, using [link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Mathematics/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: did what I could to clean up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pow` won't automatically compute a [modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) for you.  Instead, we can compute it ourselves (say via the extended Eulidean algorithm) and then rewrite `pow(a,-b,c)` as `pow((a^-1) mod c, b, c)`.  Stealing the MMI code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798654/modular-multiplicative-inverse-function-in-python):

```
def egcd(a, b):
    if a == 0:
        return (b, 0, 1)
    else:
        g, y, x = egcd(b % a, a)
        return (g, x - (b // a) * y, y)

def modinv(a, m):
    g, x, y = egcd(a, m)
    if g != 1:
        raise Exception('modular inverse does not exist')
    else:
        return x % m
```

we get

```
>>> g = 11444
>>> p = 48731
>>> w = 357
>>> modinv(g, p)
29420
>>> pow(modinv(g, p), w, p)
7355
```

Comment: In the case where `p` is prime (as it is here), a simpler implementation for `modinv(a, p)` is `pow(a, p-2, p)`.

Comment: New in python3.8: `pow` can now compute a modular multiplicative inverse. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow

Answer (score 10):

As of python 3.8 you can do this. 3.9 adds keyword arguments. Check out there code [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow). There usage is

```
>>> pow(38, -1, mod=97)
23
>>> 23 * 38 % 97 == 1
True
```