# Why doesn't x**y%z work like pow(x, y, z) if y is negative?

Tags: python, math, modulo, pow

I have these values for x, y and z:

```
x = 1402709587326125487755933770599785022011554878478352915458023572822263891029946822919389113025226898265
y = -1653150172609560595889587008271025520100868674290063537844119789327420377094035018771640253912456367085
z = 5223965736281209292468836459168070829492174759961935620654434528517414151878323192140113927287012325803
```

`pow(x,y,z)` returns `6996453002252837241098775666312149651703153544682991747419581607713`
(like it needs to be according to the RSA-assignment)

`x**y%z` should do the same, but returns `0.0`
Can someone explain why? I'm guessing it has something to do with the negative y.

Comment: I get `ValueError: pow() 2nd argument cannot be negative when 3rd argument specified` on python 3.6.13

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Negative power in modular pow()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119110/negative-power-in-modular-pow)

Comment: `x**y` is a *fraction*, which is a *floating point value* below `5.562684646268003E-309` - mimimum possible magnitude for `double`, - so you have `x ** y == 0.0`

Comment: Note that using `pow` to compute modular inverses requires Python>=3.8.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko You answered my question :)

Comment: @jakub I don't see how that's helpful.

Comment: @KellyBundy - because the OP has a negative exponent, and that causes an error when also using a mod value.

Comment: @jakub Only because you're using an old Python version. Why are you telling us that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you compute

```
x ** y % z
```

you do it in *two* steps: `(x ** y) % z`. The very first step

```
x ** y
```

returns *floating point fraction* which is by far *below* `5.562684646268003E-309` (which is the *minimum possible magnitude* for `double`). So, `x ** y == 0.0` and, finally, `0 % z == 0`