# Reversing mod for a function?

Tags: math, modulo

I'm trying to solve this equation:

```
(b(ax+b ) - c) % n = e
```

Where everything is given except `x` 
I tried the approach of :

```
(A + x) % B = C
(B + C - A) % B = x
```

where `A` is `(-c)` and then manually solve for `x` given my other subs, but I am not getting the correct output. Would I possibly need to use eea? Any help would be appreciated! I understand this question has been asked, I tried their solutions but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(b*(a*x+b) - c) % n = e`

can be rewritten as:

```
(b*a*x) % n = (e - b*b + c) % n
x = ((e - b*b + c) * modular_inverse(b*a, n)) % n
```

where the [modular inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of `u`, `modular_inverse(u, n)`,  is a number `v` such that `u*v % n == 1`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798654/modular-multiplicative-inverse-function-in-python) for code to calculate the modular inverse.

Some caveats:

- When simplifying modular equations, you can never simply divide, you need to multiply with the *modular inverse*.
- There is no straightforward formula to calculate the *modular inverse*, but there is a simple, quick algorithm to calculate it, similar to calculating the [gcd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor).
- The modular inverse doesn't always exist.
- Depending on the programming language, when one or both arguments are negative, the result of modulo can also be negative.
- As every solution works for every `x` modulo `n`, for small `n` only the numbers from `0` till `n-1` need to be tested, so in many cases a simple loop is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

What language are you doing this in, and are the variables constant?
Here's a quick way to determine the possible values of x in Java:

```
for (int x = -1000; x < 1000; x++){
    if ((b*((a*x)+b) - c) % n == e){
    System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```