# how to invers mod NP' to find the multiplier?

Tags: python, module, reverse-engineering, reverse, inverse

N=115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337

p=115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663

Gx = 18330083172231516910921476241581278950469869051063175177377276968000913867056

((N-1)* multiplier)%((N+P)/2)=Gx

how to invers mod NP' to find the multiplier?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798654/modular-multiplicative-inverse-function-in-python

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modular multiplicative inverse function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798654/modular-multiplicative-inverse-function-in-python)