# How do I decrypt using hashlib in python?

Tags: python, hashlib

I know how to encrypt:

```
encrypted = hashlib.sha256('1234').hexdigest()
```

But I am not sure, how to decrypt this?

```
decrypted = decrypt(encrypted)
```

Comment: That's not how hashing works.  In general, the whole point of a hash is that it can't be undone.  Hashing is not an encryption technique.

Comment: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) has a nice article about hashes

Comment: Just think about it. If you could "decrypt" a hash, which is very short, 32 bytes for SHA256, you would have ultimate compression method. But of course you can not, for any data that is longer than the hash, there are hash collisions, in other words different data which produce same hash (but with cryptographically secure hash like SHA256, you can't actually find or create collisions with current or foreseeable computers).

Comment: Why collisions exist with simple example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle

Comment: Only way to get back the original string back from sha1 is to brute force. There is no decrypt function for any hash function. That is the whole point of hashing. Yet sha1(small string) can be brute forced to get back the original string.

Comment: Further to the points about a hash not being "encryption" - one hash result can be produced by many different input text values - for arbitrary length inputs, any hash value can be produced by an infinite number of inputs (of different length) !

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The point of a hash like sha256 is that it is supposed to be a one way function (although the existence of true one way functions is still an open question, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function).

Note http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function:

The ideal cryptographic hash function has four main properties:

- 1. it is easy to compute the hash value for any given message
- 2. it is infeasible to generate a message that has a given hash
- 3. it is infeasible to modify a message without changing the hash
- 4. it is infeasible to find two different messages with the same hash.

If you could reverse it then you'd be breaking rule 2. These rules allow one to tell another party that they have some information (such as a password), without revealing the information. For example, see wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Illustration

If you need invertibility see [Simple way to encode a string according to a password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490334/simple-way-to-encode-a-string-according-to-a-password), you can use something weak like Vignere, but there is also an example using PyCrypto:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64

cipher = AES.new(secret_key,AES.MODE_ECB) # never use ECB in strong systems obviously
encoded = base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(msg_text))
# ...
decoded = cipher.decrypt(baes64.b64decode(msg_text))
```

If you want a reversible hash function, see [Reversible hash function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273466/reversible-hash-function)

Comment: encrypt function says `ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length`

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is you cannot 'decrypt' a hash; it is a one way function. There is a major difference between encrypting and hashing.

**Hashing**

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

Note: It is possible to 'BREAK' certain hashing algorithms, but this is not decrypting. You'll find more information in the links as well as other algorithms that are also supported by python

**Encryption**

and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption

**Example**

A useful example of hashing is storing passwords in a database whereas a useful example of encryption is sending your bank details to an online store to purchase something.

Answer (score 6):

This is a valid question, maybe not posed correctly though.

OP, I think what you're trying to do is check a hashed value against an unhashed one?

```
hashed = hashlib.sha256('1234').hexdigest()
hashedstring = '1234' + ',' + hashed
```

now to check that hashed == original value. So parse out the piece before and after the comma. Hash 1234 and compare it to the value hashed.

```
def check_secure_val(h):
    commapos = h.find(",")
    val = h[0:commapos]
    hashval = h[commapos+1:-1]
    rehashval = hash_str(val)
    if rehashval == hashval:
        return val
```

> where input h is a string of format "val,(HASHEDSTRING)"
>
> and hash_str is a function that hashes.

Answer (score 3):

The hashes are calculated using one way functions, i.e. it will give same output for a particular input but as it is only a one-way function, no matter what you do, you cannot decrypt it. One can try decrypting it by brute force, i.e calculating hashes of words from dictionary and comparing it with the hash you want to decrypt.
To save the time of calculating the hashes of dictionary words, there are rainbow tables available online which contains hashes with the words.

read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table

You can also use online services for brute force decryption of a hash. there are plenty available and works well if the word you want to decrypt belongs to a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Not-very-exact *Analogy*: Encryption is like someone wearing a disguise ... taking a Hash is like taking their fingerprints !

You can get the "original" person back by removing/reversing the disguise, but you cannot do that from a set of fingerprints !

Comment: really bad analogy

Comment: Yes,, @AkshayLAradhya as stated, it's not very exact. However, given the state of knowledge implied by the question, it conveys the degree of mismatch between expectation and reality. It's not intended to explain either hashing or encryption - just the level of difference between them.
So it depends on what you were expecting; I am fairly exacting in my teaching standards, but I thought my "answer" would convey the issue.

Answer (score 0):

this might help?

```
import hashlib

l = ["riyad", "onni", "arman"]

def check_user(h):
    for i in l:
        if h == hashlib.md5(i.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest():
            return i


print(check_user(hashlib.md5(l[2].encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can decrypt it
but what you can do is maybe take the range of guessed passwords for example in a for loop and put all of them **"{password: hashed password"** then check the hash and maybe you'll get it

so let's say you wanna crack a password that is in a CSV file and is between 0000-9999

the input csv file would be like :

name, hashed password

first we'll import csv and hashlib

```
import hashlib
import csv
```

now lets write a function that takes the hashed csv file and output csv file as arguments
we'll make an empty string and an empty dict

```
def decryptor(input_file_name,output_file_name):
    # makes hashes
    clear_text = ""
    mydict = {}
```

now lets make a for loop in range of 0 and 9999
and we will encypt every number in that range

```
    for i in range(0, 10000):
        i = str(i).encode('utf-8') 
        encrypted = hashlib.sha256(i).hexdigest()
        mydict[i] = encrypted
```

now we'll just write them in csv file

```
    with open(input_file_name, 'r') as hash_file:
        # read's from csv file
        reader = csv.reader(hash_file)
        hash_dict = {}
        # reades every line of csv file
        for row in reader:
                hash_dict[row[0]] = row[1]
```

now we just need to check the hash we wanna decrypt with the hashes we already have and we'll get the unhashed password

```
    check_hash = []
    for i in list(mydict):
        text = "%s" % (mydict[i])
        check_hash.append(mydict[i])
    for i in list(hash_dict):
        if hash_dict[i] in check_hash:
            hashes = list(mydict.keys())[list(mydict.values()).index(hash_dict[i])]
            names = list(hash_dict.keys())[list(hash_dict.values()).index(hash_dict[i])],
            text = "%s,%s\n" % (names[0], hashes.decode('utf-8'))
            clear_text += text
```

now we write the out put to the output csv file

```
    with open(output_file_name, 'w') as passwords:
        passwords.write(clear_text)
```

and we'll just call the function

```
decryptor(<INPUT CSV>, <OUTPUT CSV NAME>)
```

This is my idea for you of cource you can't use this this is an idea hope it'll help :)

Comment: please added a descript answer and a simple code so you answer can be useful

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: hey sorry for not embedding any codes I'll do it right now