# Pandas: Create new index column by mapping existing column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a column

```
col1
----
a
b
c
a
c
b
```

I have a mapping like this :

```
KI13232:a
MK25436:b
SL365487:c
```

That means, create a new column with name `ID` and for all occurrences of `a` in the `col1` the `ID` column value should be  `KI13232`, same applies to b and c values as well.

The result should look like :

```
ID        col1
----      -----
KI13232    a
MK25436    b
SL365487   c
KI13232    a
SL365487   c
MK25436    b
```

I have a larger dataset to implement this. What is the optimal method in Pandas to achieve this.

Comment: What is the point of mapping values to keys? Shouldn't the values be the keys in the first place? Also, how are you going to manage keys with duplicate values?

Comment: I didn't wrote it as dict. It is another table with these mappings. `a`,`b` and `c` could be keys. I just need new column with correct mapping. Hope it make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) with `dict comprehension` for swap keys with values of `dict`:

```
d = {'KI13232':'a','MK25436':'b','SL365487':'c'}

df['ID'] = df['col1'].map({v:k for  k, v in d.items()})
```

Or similar:

```
df['ID'] = df['col1'].map(dict(zip(d.values(),d.keys())))
```

---

```
print (df)
  col1        ID
0    a   KI13232
1    b   MK25436
2    c  SL365487
3    a   KI13232
4    c  SL365487
5    b   MK25436
```

If order of column is important add [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
df.insert(0, 'ID', df['col1'].map({v:k for  k, v in d.items()}))
print (df)
         ID col1
0   KI13232    a
1   MK25436    b
2  SL365487    c
3   KI13232    a
4  SL365487    c
5   MK25436    b
```

And for index:

```
df.index = df['col1'].map({v:k for  k, v in d.items()}).rename('ID')
print (df)
         col1
ID           
KI13232     a
MK25436     b
SL365487    c
KI13232     a
SL365487    c
MK25436     b
```

Comment: Yes, it depends of dict.

Comment: it [annoys me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493129/injective-two-way-mappings) that a proper injective construct doesn't exist. i think it would be commonly used if available!

Answer (score 2):

Borrow Jez's dict

```
df['New']=df.col1.replace(d.values(),d.keys())
df
Out[921]: 
  col1       New
0    a   KI13232
1    b   MK25436
2    c  SL365487
3    a   KI13232
4    c  SL365487
5    b   MK25436
```