# Is there a .NET encryption library that implements AES 256 encryption as a Stream?

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I'd like to be able to encrypt / decrypt data as it's streamed to/from disk.
I know I could write my own Stream and implement the encryption there, but I'd rather not risk doing it wrong. Is there a library that works in a similar way to the following code?

```
byte[] encryptionKey = ;
byte[] initVector = ;

var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
var encryptionStream = new AesEncryptionStream(fileStream, initVector, encryptionKey);
var gzStream = new GZipStream(encryptionStream, CompressionMode.Compress);
var writer = new BinaryWriter(gzStream);
```

Comment: You should encrypt after compressing

Comment: Have seen [a great implementation of AES Encryption at Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165808/simple-2-way-encryption-for-c/212707#212707) itself. I am using it ever since. Check if it suits your purpose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for the `RijndaelManaged` and `CryptoStream` classes:

```
var aes = new RijndaelManaged { Key = ..., IV = ... };

using (var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor()) 
using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(gzStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(cryptoStream)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: @SLaks: is using necessary on CryptoStream? btw congrats on being elected as a mod.my vote would need a treat. :)

Comment: "using" is not required, but it's a good practice with short-lived disposables like this. If you don't use using, make sure you dispose of all these when you're done. I think all of these just MIGHT implement a finalizer, but best not to test that.

Comment: I asked these because a guy noted in a comment(link in my answer) that "there's no benefit to Disposing of MemoryStreams -- they're not like normal streams that hold an OS resource -- they just hold a buffer object that will be collected as all other in-memory objects will be" How valid is this?

Comment: @yet: He's right.  However, CryptoStreams aren't MemoryStreams.  Dispose calls FlushFinalBlock if necessary, and clears sensitive data.

Comment: @Keith: Here, it is required.  Otherwise, the final chunk won't be written.

Comment: @SLaks: well, flushing/closing the CryptoStream manually would do the same, yes? I find it hard to believe that with the functionality provided by Stream, there's only one pattern for use of a CryptoStream that actually works.