# WPF login authentication

Tags: c#, wpf, encryption, authentication

I doing a WPF project using C# and LinQ. My application require user to login before they able to access the application. So, what i am doing is i have all the members data in mySQL server(as shown as the image below). User able to login into the application only if the **"Status"** is **1**. So, may i know what kind method i can use for all the authentication and encryption for the login procedure? Thanks.

p/s: i am a newbie

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do something like this:

```
   var username = txtUserName.Text;
   var password = txtPassword.Text;// there is available encryption on the web that you can use on. and your code will be like var password=enc.EncryptToString(txtPassword.Text);
   var isValidUser = from user on UserTable
                     where user.UserName == txtUserName.Text && user.Password == password && user.Status == 1
                     select user;  
   if(isValiduser.Count() > 0)
   {
     //OK you can log on
   }
   else
   {
     //user credential is invalid
   }
```

For your encryption see the link below for:

[Simple 2 way encryption for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165808/simple-2-way-encryption-for-c-sharp)

Best Regards

Comment: ha, actually i did something like that. +1 for you and mark the "tick" for you if the encryption work. thanks for the quick reply C=