# An easy way to encrypt and decrypt with a key

Tags: c#, cryptography

I'm looking for an easy way to encrypt and decrypt some data using a fixed key (which will be stored in my configurations) and store the result as string (base16 or hex).

Something like

```
string myString = "hello world";
string myKey = "k2k3aij3h";
string enc = new Algorithm().Encrypt(myString, myKey);
string dec = new Alrorithm().Decrypt(enc, myKey);
```

Comment: The one I'm looking for.. anyone! I just want an easy step to do that, like examplified.

Comment: I'm checking if there is some already done in .net framework.

Comment: The search box can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165808/simple-2-way-encryption-for-c-sharp?rq=1

Comment: This totally depend on what and how much you want to encrypt. There are many APIs for the same. You need to select the best that fits in your application

Comment: @AtishDipongkor Have you written many of your own good secure encryption algorithms lately that stand up to a beating?

Comment: @Fabricio you should not decrypt a password. To match encrypted the password with same key and algorithm then match the with original one. The value that can be decrypted is not string encryption algorithm.

Comment: Have you looked in System.Cryptography? There's a whole namespace dedicated to it.

Comment: You could always use ROT13

Comment: @Fabricio, I had the same problem a while back and solved it with a c# implementation of Rinjdael.  It worked totally great, and I recommend it.  I still have the source laying around if you really need it too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this

```
       private const string initVector = "tu89geji340t89u2";

        private const int keysize = 256;

        public static string Encrypt(string Text, string Key)
        {
            byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(initVector);
            byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Text);
            PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Key, null);
            byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
            RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
            symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            byte[] Encrypted = memoryStream.ToArray();
            memoryStream.Close();
            cryptoStream.Close();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypted);
        }

        public static string Decrypt(string EncryptedText, string Key)
        {
            byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVector);
            byte[] DeEncryptedText = Convert.FromBase64String(EncryptedText);
            PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Key, null);
            byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
            RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
            symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(DeEncryptedText);
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
            byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[DeEncryptedText.Length];
            int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
            memoryStream.Close();
            cryptoStream.Close();
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
        }
```

it's from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168240/encrypting-decrypting-a-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: A static IV is not the correct way to do this. It will cause various security issues. The "Key" parameter is named wrong here, since it's passed to a key derivation function. Using a KDF without a salt is wrong too. What I'm trying to say is that cryptography is hard, and you really have to know what you're doing to use it correctly – copy-pasting code from the internet won't make it any easier.

Comment: -1 Dislike cut and paste of incorrect crypto that was written to "work" but doesn't really.

Comment: Not good encryption code. Avoid copy&paste from other sites