# How do I encrypt entire URL or display static URL on asp.net web application?

Tags: c#

I want to encrypt entire URL of my web page displayed in Address bar of the browser. Or just want to display static url.
I need the generic code for this so that whenever I redirect to any page of my web application then also in address bar url should not change.

Comment: You should not have multiple distinct webpages residing under the same web address. Also, your url must at least point to your server, though you could create a system like `http://www.yourdomain.com/seeminglyrandomvaluehere`

Answer (score 0):

You can display different views with same url in MVC by using return View("name"); insted of return RedirectToAction("name"); 
I did this for some parts of a web app where it was needed. If you want the whole page to be with one static url I think you could run into some issues with this.

For encryption you could use this and then decrypt calls to do what they should. 
[An easy way to encrypt and decrypt with a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17213851/an-easy-way-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-with-a-key)