# C# calling SimpleAES class

Tags: c#, class

I'am trying to encrypt and decrypt a text string by calling a SimpleAES class which i got from this accepted anwser [Simple 2 way encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165808/simple-2-way-encryption-for-c-sharp)

My problem is how to call this class from Form1 and get the encrypted/decrypted anwser returned?

I tried the following:

```
private void encryptbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string encryptkey = inputtxt.Text;
    SimpleAES simpleAES1 = new SimpleAES();
    simpleAES1.EncryptToString(encryptkey);
    decrypttxt.Text = encryptkey.ToString();
}
```

Tried to find some basics on classes but couldn't find any covering returning from a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the class in the accepted answer, you'll see the `EncryptToString()` returns a string, so:

```
string encryptedText = simpleAES1.EncryptToString(encryptkey);
```

In general, you can get values from classes via properties and methods (if the method specifies a return type).

Also, you don't need to call `ToString()` on `encryptkey`, as it's already a string.

Answer (score 2):

You are ignoring the return value of the function `SimpleAES.EncryptToString`. Store the result in a temporary variable called `cipherText` and then assign that to the `TextBox.Text` property.

```
private void encryptbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string encryptkey = inputtxt.Text;
    SimpleAES simpleAES1 = new SimpleAES();
    string cipherText = simpleAES1.EncryptToString(encryptkey);
    decrypttxt.Text = cipherText ;
}
```

Comment: +1 - I think you understood what `decrypttxt` was for better than I did (OP wants to write the output to the TextBox).  An even shorter way would be to simply do `decrypttxt.Text = simpleAES1.EncryptToString(encryptKey);`