# Simple encryption algorithm in c#.net

Tags: c#

I am trying to read the text from the file nad encrypt it and pass it to a function in string format.
Later I also want to decrypt it.

I tried the following but it didn't do any encryption.Can anyone suggest any simple encryption algorithm?

```
fileStream = store.OpenFile(strFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
strEncryptedFileStream = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(fileStream.ToString()).ToString();
```

Comment: Which code do you think will do the encryption in what you posted?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165808/simple-2-way-encryption-for-c-sharp

Comment: what you did is essentially getting an unicode byte array of your string populated from an entire file

Comment: Encryption != Encoding

Comment: [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13). Can't go much simpler than that. :) If you need a bit more protection, you could try DoubleROT13. ;)

Answer (score 16):

Use [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard). Here is a helper class for it. There is no sense using a "simple", or in other words, easily broken encryption. Either you want people to be able to break it, or you don't. Choose an encryption standard that is well known and tested.

You may be able to modify the example below for your needs if it does not fulfill them.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Common.Cryptography
{
    /// <summary>
    /// AES is a symmetric 256-bit encryption algorthm.
    /// Read more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard
    /// </summary>
    public static class AES
    {
        private const string _SALT = "g46dzQ80";
        private const string _INITVECTOR = "OFRna74m*aze01xY";

        private static byte[] _saltBytes;
        private static byte[] _initVectorBytes;

        static AES()
        {
            _saltBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_SALT);
            _initVectorBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_INITVECTOR);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Encrypts a string with AES
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="plainText">Text to be encrypted</param>
        /// <param name="password">Password to encrypt with</param>   
        /// <param name="salt">Salt to encrypt with</param>    
        /// <param name="initialVector">Needs to be 16 ASCII characters long</param>    
        /// <returns>An encrypted string</returns>        
        public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string password, string salt = null, string initialVector = null)
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(EncryptToBytes(plainText, password, salt, initialVector));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Encrypts a string with AES
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="plainText">Text to be encrypted</param>
        /// <param name="password">Password to encrypt with</param>   
        /// <param name="salt">Salt to encrypt with</param>    
        /// <param name="initialVector">Needs to be 16 ASCII characters long</param>    
        /// <returns>An encrypted string</returns>        
        public static byte[] EncryptToBytes(string plainText, string password, string salt = null, string initialVector = null)
        {
            byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            return EncryptToBytes(plainTextBytes, password, salt, initialVector);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Encrypts a string with AES
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="plainTextBytes">Bytes to be encrypted</param>
        /// <param name="password">Password to encrypt with</param>   
        /// <param name="salt">Salt to encrypt with</param>    
        /// <param name="initialVector">Needs to be 16 ASCII characters long</param>    
        /// <returns>An encrypted string</returns>        
        public static byte[] EncryptToBytes(byte[] plainTextBytes, string password, string salt = null, string initialVector = null)
        {
            int keySize = 256;

            byte[] initialVectorBytes = string.IsNullOrEmpty(initialVector) ? _initVectorBytes : Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(initialVector);
            byte[] saltValueBytes = string.IsNullOrEmpty(salt) ? _saltBytes : Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt);
            byte[] keyBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltValueBytes).GetBytes(keySize / 8);

            using (RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initialVectorBytes))
                {
                    using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

                            return memStream.ToArray();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>  
        /// Decrypts an AES-encrypted string. 
        /// </summary>  
        /// <param name="cipherText">Text to be decrypted</param> 
        /// <param name="password">Password to decrypt with</param> 
        /// <param name="salt">Salt to decrypt with</param> 
        /// <param name="initialVector">Needs to be 16 ASCII characters long</param> 
        /// <returns>A decrypted string</returns>
        public static string Decrypt(string cipherText, string password, string salt = null, string initialVector = null)
        {
            byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText.Replace(' ','+'));
            return Decrypt(cipherTextBytes, password, salt, initialVector).TrimEnd('\0');
        }

        /// <summary>  
        /// Decrypts an AES-encrypted string. 
        /// </summary>  
        /// <param name="cipherText">Text to be decrypted</param> 
        /// <param name="password">Password to decrypt with</param> 
        /// <param name="salt">Salt to decrypt with</param> 
        /// <param name="initialVector">Needs to be 16 ASCII characters long</param> 
        /// <returns>A decrypted string</returns>
        public static string Decrypt(byte[] cipherTextBytes, string password, string salt = null, string initialVector = null)
        {
            int keySize = 256;

            byte[] initialVectorBytes = string.IsNullOrEmpty(initialVector) ? _initVectorBytes : Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(initialVector);
            byte[] saltValueBytes = string.IsNullOrEmpty(salt) ? _saltBytes : Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt);
            byte[] keyBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltValueBytes).GetBytes(keySize / 8);
            byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];

            using (RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initialVectorBytes))
                {
                    using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes))
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                        {
                            int byteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);

                            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, byteCount);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I decrypt such a string in another language, e.g. PHP?

Comment: All correct implementations of AES *should* be able to encrypt and decrypt interchangeably regardless of language if you use the same salt, initial vector (iv), and key values. That said, not all languages have implemented this in the same way. PHP with openssl_encrypt derrives the salt from the key. It looks like this lib tries to implement encryption across many languages but not all are well polished: https://github.com/RNCryptor

Comment: Nice and simple. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in your code does encryption. You're just converting it to Unicode.

You could take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165808/simple-2-way-encryption-for-c-sharp) which gives a good example of encryption in C#.

Answer (score 0):

The method Enconding concerns the Text Encoding (UTF-8, ANSI, etc ...) you should use an encryption algorithm, there are several ways to do this, A simple example would be using XOR encryption.

See this:

```
string XorEncryptDecryptText(string stringText, string stringKey){
// Variable that receives the result of processode encryption.
string stringNewText = &quot;&quot;;
// First we take the difference in size of the two strings.
int diff = (stringText.Length - stringKey.Length);
// If the size difference that we put stringKey with the same size as the XOR stringText that no errors occur.
if (diff &gt; 0){
    // We calculate the rest and the amount of times we repeat the stringKey to equal sizes.
    int cont = (int)diff / stringKey.Length;
    int resto = diff % stringKey.Length;
    string stringKeyAux = stringKey;
    // At this point the stringText concatenate the stringKey to be equal sizes.
    for (int i = 0; i &lt; cont; i++){
        stringKeyAux += stringKey;
    }

    for (int i = 0; (i &lt; resto); i++){
        stringKeyAux += stringKey[i];
    }
    stringKey = stringKeyAux;
}
// At this point piece of code is done the process of XOR.
for (int i = 0; i &lt; stringText.Length; i++){
    int charValue = Convert.ToInt32(stringText[i]);
    int charKey = Convert.ToInt32(stringKey[i]);
    charValue ^= charKey;
    stringNewText += char.ConvertFromUtf32(charValue);
}
return stringNewText;}

string XOREncriptDecriptFile(string FileName, string stringKey){
string stringAux = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FileName);
return XorEncryptDecryptText(stringAux, stringKey);}
```

This code is based on http://julioborges.p.ht/?p=769.

For more security use the answer of [smdrager](https://stackoverflow.com/users/356550/smdrager)