# AES encryption in c# and compare result in file level

Tags: c#, encryption, file-io, aes

new to AES, I visited several threads about it, ex: examples of Dan Esparza, Zeeshan Amber at this thread [Simple encryption algorithm in c#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549775/simple-encryption-algorithm-in-c-net) , and smdrager at [Simple encryption algorithm in c#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549775/simple-encryption-algorithm-in-c-net/17549863#17549863)

I tried to use some examples in my case, but I found something incorrect, let me explain:

1. I want to encrypt a binary file (named "exa" ).
2. I use git to check whether output file is different from input file.
3. I read input file to stream(byte[] or string).
4. Just after that, write to a different file by using File.WriteAllBytes() right away. ( make sure the reading bytes are right , **succseed** )
5. Then, I used the examples of Dan Esparza, smdrager, Zeeshan Amber
6. Every time I finished, I compared the decrypt bytes in memory from the original ones and see if the bytes different.
7. I saved the decrypt result to file and compare.
8. The results are all disappointing, all files failed, but in some cases the bytes comparison are fine.

## The example of smdrager

```
byte[] orgBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("exa");

byte[] encQuote = EncryptByteToBytes(orgBytes , "password" );
byte[] endByte = DecryptToByte(encQuote, "password");

File.WriteAllBytes("exaOutputBytes", endByte);
```

The comparison failed in byte number, also failed in file comparison.

```
orgBytes.Length : 55732
endByte.Length : 55744
```

## The example of Dan Esparza

In this case, bytes input will fail, therefore, I read by text with ASCII.

```
        string original = File.ReadAllText("exa" , Encoding.ASCII );

        using (RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
        {

            myRijndael.GenerateKey();
            myRijndael.GenerateIV();
            // Encrypt the string to an array of bytes. 
            byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes(original, myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV);

            // Decrypt the bytes to a string. 
            string roundtrip = DecryptStringFromBytes(encrypted, myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV);

            File.WriteAllText("exaOutputString", roundtrip , Encoding.ASCII);
```

The bytes comparison was fine, both in length and each byte content. But file comparison still failed.

## The example of Zeeshan Amber

I use password and iv the same as example.

```
            Crypt cryptObj = new Crypt();

            string encryStr = cryptObj.Encrypt(original, "AGARAMUDHALA", "EZHUTHELLAM", "SHA1", 3, "@1B2c3D4e5F6g7H8", 256);
            string decryStr = cryptObj.Decrypt(encryStr, "AGARAMUDHALA", "EZHUTHELLAM", "SHA1", 3, "@1B2c3D4e5F6g7H8", 256);
```

In this case, the same with Dan Esparza , failed in file comparison.

I think the problem should be at my file importing/exporting, maybe special character in file, EOL, or BOM. I also tried different encoding when writing files, but found nothing.

Does anyone have something in mind?

Comment: If you want to transfer bytes, don't treat them as text. If you must, use an encoding like CP437 that has the essential property of 256 codepoints encoded as values 0 to 255 with no invalid sequences—in other words, arbitrary bytes. ASCII, Windows-1252, UTF-8, etc don't have this property.

Comment: I see. Those code I found may only work on text input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why do you need the password in the encryption/decryption process and why do you encrypt/decrypt strings when you are basically working with bytes (files).

Here is an example using bytes and key/iv (pseudo)randomly generated:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace AesDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] key = null;
            byte[] iv = null;
            byte[] bytesToEncrypt = null;
            byte[] encryptedBytes = null;
            byte[] decryptedBytes = null;

            // generate key and iv to use for encryption/decryption. 
            using (RijndaelManaged aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                aesAlg.GenerateKey();
                aesAlg.GenerateIV();
                key = aesAlg.Key;
                iv = aesAlg.IV;
            }

            // original bytes
            bytesToEncrypt = File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\exe");
            Console.WriteLine("Bytes read: {0}",bytesToEncrypt.Length);

            // encrypt
            encryptedBytes = CryptoAes.Encrypt(bytesToEncrypt, key, iv);
            Console.WriteLine("Encrypted bytes length: {0}", encryptedBytes.Length);

            // decrypt
            decryptedBytes = CryptoAes.Decrypt(encryptedBytes, key, iv);
            Console.WriteLine("Decrypted bytes length: {0}", decryptedBytes.Length);

            // compare
            Console.WriteLine("Decrypted bytes same as original bytes: {0}", Convert.ToBase64String(decryptedBytes) == Convert.ToBase64String(bytesToEncrypt));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    internal sealed class CryptoAes
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Encrypts data with symetric key
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data">Data to be encrypted</param>
        /// <param name="key">Symetric key</param>
        /// <param name="iv">Initialization vector</param>
        /// <returns>Encrypted data</returns>
        public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
        {
            byte[] encryptedData = null;

            if (data == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("data");

            if (data == key)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

            if (data == iv)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("iv");

            using (RijndaelManaged aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = key;
                aesAlg.IV = iv;

                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
                encryptedData = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            return encryptedData;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Decrypts data with symetric key
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data">Encrypted data</param>
        /// <param name="key">Symetric key</param>
        /// <param name="iv">Initialization vector</param>
        /// <returns>Decrypted data</returns>
        public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
        {
            byte[] decryptedData = null;

            if (data == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("data");

            if (data == key)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

            if (data == iv)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("iv");

            using (RijndaelManaged aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = key;
                aesAlg.IV = iv;

                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
                decryptedData = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            return decryptedData;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great, file comparison succeed.

Answer (score 0):

**ASE file encryption**

```
internal const string Inputkey = "560A18CD-6346-4CF0-A2E8-671F9B6B9EA9";
    ///<summary>
    /// Arvind - 23/11/2017.
    ///
    /// Encrypts a file using Rijndael algorithm.
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="inputFile"></param>
    ///<param name="outputFile"></param>
    public static void EncryptFile(string inputFile, string outputFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string password = @"+kdkdkdjd8656589$**hh$^JHJBKLJJH#$$$__+0-f5546%$$^5434+"; // Secret Key
            UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
            byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password);

            string cryptFile = outputFile;
            FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(cryptFile, FileMode.Create);
            Rijndael RMCrypto = NewRijndaelManaged(password);

            var encryptor = RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(RMCrypto.Key, RMCrypto.IV);

            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt,
                encryptor,
                CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);

            int data;
            while ((data = fsIn.ReadByte()) != -1)
                cs.WriteByte((byte)data);


            fsIn.Close();
            cs.Close();
            fsCrypt.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Encryption failed!" + ex.Message);
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new RijndaelManaged class and initialize it
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="salt" />The pasword salt
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static RijndaelManaged NewRijndaelManaged(string salt)
    {
        if (salt == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("salt");
        var saltBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt);
        var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Inputkey, saltBytes);

        var aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
        aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);
        aesAlg.IV = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.BlockSize / 8);

        return aesAlg;
    }

    **File decryption**
///<summary>
    /// Arvind - 23/11/2017.
    ///
    /// Decrypts a file using Rijndael algorithm.
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="inputFile"></param>
    ///<param name="outputFile"></param>
    public static void DecryptDatabaseFile(string inputFile, string outputFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["encryptionKey"];
            UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
            byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password);

            FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);
            var aesAlg = NewRijndaelManaged(password);
            var decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt,
               decryptor,
                CryptoStreamMode.Read);

            FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create);
            int data;
            while ((data = cs.ReadByte()) != -1)
                fsOut.WriteByte((byte)data);

            fsOut.Close();
            cs.Close();
            fsCrypt.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("decryption Fail!!" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```